# Java implementations of the Prototype Pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

What implementations of the [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) Pattern exist on the Java platform?

> A prototype pattern is a creational design pattern used in software development when the type of objects to create is determined by a prototypical instance, which is cloned to produce new objects.

[Prototype based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming):

> Prototype-based programming is a style of object-oriented programming in which classes are not present, and behavior reuse (known as inheritance in class-based languages) is performed via a process of cloning existing objects that serve as prototypes.

The implementation should be aware that some Java objects are mutable, and some are immutable (see [Mutable vs Immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Josh Bloch and Doug Lea, [Cloneable is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html). In that case, you can use a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12).

Comment: Thanks for this link - I've also added a reference to mutable/immutable objects in the question.

Comment: `Object.clone` is broken. But cloning manually is still fine.

Comment: This distinction really is what I wanted to suggest. ie Cloneable as a marker interface, and void clone throws CloneNotSupportedException

Answer (score 0):

Java defines the [Cloneable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface, described here at [JGuru](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=255004)

> Java provides a simple interface named Cloneable that provides an implementation of the Prototype pattern. If you have an object that is Cloneable, you can call its clone() method to create a new instance of the object with the same values.

Warning: see [Cloneable is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Steve Yegge](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html) describes the [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) implementation of the [ASTNode](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/package-summary.html)