# mutable fields for objects in a Java Set

Tags: java, collections, identity, mutable

Am I correct in assuming that if you have an object that is contained inside a Java Set<> (or as a key in a Map<> for that matter), any fields that are used to determine identity or relation (via `hashCode()`, `equals()`, `compareTo()` etc.) cannot be changed without causing unspecified behavior for operations on the collection? (edit: as alluded to in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects))

(In other words, these fields should either be immutable, or you should require the object to be removed from the collection, then changed, then reinserted.)

The reason I ask is that I was reading the [Hibernate Annotations reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2770) and it has an example where there is a `HashSet<Toy>` but the `Toy` class has fields `name` and `serial` that are mutable and are also used in the `hashCode()` calculation... a red flag went off in my head and I just wanted to make sure I understood the implications of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The javadoc for `Set` says

> Note: Great care must be exercised if
>   mutable objects are used as set
>   elements. The behavior of a set is not
>   specified if the value of an object is
>   changed in a manner that affects
>   equals comparisons while the object is
>   an element in the set. A special case
>   of this prohibition is that it is not
>   permissible for a set to contain
>   itself as an element.

This simply means you can use mutable objects in a set, and even change them. You just should make sure the change doesn't impact the way the `Set` finds the items. For `HashSet`, that would require not changing the fields used for calculating `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct, it can cause some problems locating the map entry. Officially the behavior is undefined, so if you add it to a hashset or as a key in a hashmap, you should not be changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will cause bad things to happen.

```
// Given that the Toy class has a mutable field called 'name' which is used
// in equals() and hashCode():
Set<Toy> toys = new HashSet<Toy>();
Toy toy = new Toy("Fire engine", ToyType.WHEELED_VEHICLE, Color.RED);
toys.add(toy);
System.out.println(toys.contains(toy)); // true
toy.setName("Fast truck");
System.out.println(toys.contains(toy)); // false
```

Comment: Wait, I just realized this was a really bad example. Since I still had hold of the reference, the last contains() will in fact return true. HashMaps are a different matter, but it's almost quitting time on a three-day weekend and I don't want to dig up an example.

Comment: heh, post something when you get back -- I look forward to it.

Comment: Wait again, I forgot that HashSet uses a HashMap as backing. This could indeed happen: the backing HashMap uses the hashCode to jump to a bucket before checking equals() on the elements in the bucket, and changing an element will cause it to jump to the wrong bucket and not find any elements there.

Answer (score 0):

In a HashSet/HashMap, you *could* mutate a contained object to change the results of `compareTo()` operation -- relative comparison isn't used to locate objects. But it'd be fatal inside a TreeSet/TreeMap.

You can also mutate objects that are inside an IdentityHashMap -- nothing other than object identity is used to locate contents.

Even though you can do these things with these qualifications, they make your code more fragile. What if someone wants to change to a TreeSet later, or add that mutable field to the hashCode/equality test?