# Difference between Mutable objects and Immutable objects

Tags: java, terminology

Any one please give the diff between Mutable objects and Immutable objects with example.

Comment: `String` class is a great example of an immutable object.

Comment: See also [Mutable vs immutable objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects) (not Java-specific)

Comment: btw, take a look at [`com.jcabi.aspects.Immutable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-immutable.html) annotation

Answer (score 133):

Mutable objects have fields that can be changed, immutable objects have no fields that can be changed after the object is created.

A very simple immutable object is a object without any field. (For example a simple Comparator Implementation).

```
class Mutable{
  private int value;

  public Mutable(int value) {
     this.value = value;
  }

  //getter and setter for value
}

class Immutable {
  private final int value;

  public Immutable(int value) {
     this.value = value;
  }

  //only getter
}
```

Answer (score 69):

Mutable objects can have their fields changed after construction. Immutable objects cannot.

```
public class MutableClass {

 private int value;

 public MutableClass(int aValue) {
  value = aValue;
 }

 public void setValue(int aValue) {
  value = aValue;
 }

 public getValue() {
  return value;
 }

}

public class ImmutableClass {

 private final int value;
 // changed the constructor to say Immutable instead of mutable
 public ImmutableClass (final int aValue) {
  //The value is set. Now, and forever.
  value = aValue;
 }

 public final getValue() {
  return value;
 }

}
```

Comment: +1 as you answered before @Ralph and more explicitly

Answer (score 32):

Immutable objects are simply objects whose state (the object's data) cannot change after construction. Examples of immutable objects from the JDK include String and Integer.

For example:(Point is mutable and string immutable)

```
     Point myPoint = new Point( 0, 0 );
    System.out.println( myPoint );
    myPoint.setLocation( 1.0, 0.0 );
    System.out.println( myPoint );

    String myString = new String( "old String" );
    System.out.println( myString );
    myString.replaceAll( "old", "new" );
    System.out.println( myString );
```

The output is:

```
java.awt.Point[0.0, 0.0]
java.awt.Point[1.0, 0.0]
old String
old String
```

Comment: Good 'ol Effective Java.

Comment: This is what i m looking for ... THanks

Comment: myString.replaceAll( "old", "new" );  -- This code must be like that myString=myString.replaceAll( "old", "new" );  -- I think you have used it in wrong way .

Comment: @TugrulAsik  - Ma friend, he used that in correct way only. replace/replaceAll methods will return the value. If u want that store to a string and use it. Either u can store to same string or create a new string object and use it.

Comment: What exactly happened when `myString.replaceAll( "old", "new" );`.  Did that do nothing or did it create a new string with value "new String" but since we did not store it, it got lost. What happened?

Answer (score 22):

[*Immutable*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) Object's state cannot be altered.

for example `String`.

```
String str= "abc";//a object of string is created
str  = str + "def";// a new object of string is created and assigned to str
```

Answer (score 15):

They are not different from the point of view of JVM. Immutable objects don't have methods that can change the instance variables. And the instance variables are private; therefore you can't change it after you create it. A famous example would be String. You don't have methods like setString, or setCharAt. And s1 = s1 + "w" will create a new string, with the original one abandoned.
That's my understanding.

Comment: ... and all instance variables are private! (otherwise -> mutable)

Comment: @Andreas_D - Thank you for reminding. I guess I took it as granted.

Comment: upvoted for "They are not different from the point of view of JVM"