# Is this class Immutable?

Tags: java, immutability

```
public final class Multi {
    private final String name;
    private final int number;
    private final ArrayList<String> otherNames;

    Multi(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.otherNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addOtherNames(String name) {
        this.otherNames.add(name);
    }


    // All getter methods should be a copy of the class fields
    public ArrayList<String> getOtherNames() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(otherNames);
    }  
}
```

I am having some trouble understanding immutability when it involves data structures such as ArrayList ect.

When I have a method such as addOtherNames which will add contents to the list after object creation.

Thanks

Comment: If there is a way to change the data inside the object after it has been constructed, then it is mutable.

Comment: No, this is not immutable.  If `addOtherNames` weren't there, it probably would be.

Comment: I don't think this one is immutable object.There is similar question in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658453/difference-between-mutable-objects-and-immutable-objects

Comment: @Socowi Good point. Having the *exposed API to mutate the object state* (via contained type or not) is something hard to argue against.. however, "strictly", since all the fields are final I could also argue with splitting hairs *if* there was no exposed API.

Comment: getOtherNames returns a new ArrayList, so adding values to it shouldn't have any effect on the internal one.

Comment: It has shallow immutability but not deep immutability.

Comment: @Socowi I would have thought that by creating a new arrayList it should not affect the internal List?

Comment: @JordanDixon I was wrong. Please excuse the confusion. But still, there's the method `addOtherNames`.

Comment: 'Immutability' is not particularly well-defined so it's sort of [open to interpretation](http://www.yegor256.com/2016/09/07/gradients-of-immutability.html). Some would say its immutable because all of the fields are final. Others would argue it is not immutable because it contains a mutable object. Most of the things people praise immutable objects for - i.e. thread safety, etc. - come *only* with the objects that are completely **constant** so I favour the latter opinion.

Comment: so the addOtherNames makes this class mutable?

Comment: Yes, `addOtherNames()` allows the list to be mutated after construction so the state of the class is mutable.

Answer (score -3):

Technically, it's immutable.

But an object you can reach through it (otherNames) is not, so it's not thread safe.

Comment: This answer is misleading because the object only has shallow immutability, not deep immutability.

Comment: So a shallow lake *is not* a lake, but a deep lake *is* a lake, EJoshuaS?

Comment: No, a puddle is not a lake.