# Parametrized POCO Constructors with the Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design, poco, code-first

According to [Initial POCO Design 1-Pager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/06/24/initial-poco-design-1-pager.aspx)

> Persistence Ignorance refers to being
>   able to allow the developer to write
>   and test domain objects in a way that
>   is entirely independent of fundamental
>   requirements and assumptions that may
>   be made by the infrastructure service
>   (in this case, the Entity Framework).
>   Such requirements / assumptions may
>   often include:
>
> - The need to implement a specific interface (for e.g., IPOCO)
> - Inheritance from a base class
> - **Providing specific constructors**
> - Object Instantiation/Construction requirements – use a specific factory
>     for instance**
> - The need for metadata or mapping class or property Attributes
> - The need to use specific relationship mechanisms
>
> This amounts to being able to use
>   Plain Old CLR Objects (POCO) so that a
>   developer can author their domain
>   objects free of all assumptions and
>   requirements imposed by the framework.
>   Using this approach, once the domain
>   objects are ready to their
>   satisfaction, the developer can use
>   these classes with the Entity
>   Framework in order for relational
>   database access and persistence.

As of right now (CTP5), is there any way at all to reconstitute a poco using a parametrized constructor?  If not, it's hard to see how the Entity Framework can be said to offer persistence ignorance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have as many parameterized constructors as you want, so long as the framework has access to a parameter-less one, which is available by default if you you have no constructors, or if you provide one in addition to the parameterized ones you create.

Comment: So much for having immutable domain objects, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.   Domain Objects "have a life of their own" and have attributes that change.  Are you talking about Value Objects?

Comment: No, I am talking about objects where some of the attributes are not to be changed after construction. See [Mutable vs immutable objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects)

Comment: In that case, you will still be able to mark your setters as private.  You're still good to go!  (This also applies to value objects.)

Comment: Also important to note that your parameterless constructor doesn't have to be public.  It works with private or protected just as well.

Comment: Any source about the requirment for a parameterless constructor?