# Qt C++ function breaks deleting unknown variable

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple gui that has a text field, a drop-down menu, and a go button. I can specify the name and class of a part I'm looking for, and call a function by connecting the "go" button to a slot that runs a function that I already made.

However, when the slot function is done with everything, it calls a function in `xstring`, that's deleting some massive `xstring`. It goes to this function:

```
void _Tidy(bool _Built = false,
    size_type _Newsize = 0)
    {   // initialize buffer, deallocating any storage
    if (!_Built)
        ;
    else if (this->_BUF_SIZE <= this->_Myres)
        {   // copy any leftovers to small buffer and deallocate
        pointer _Ptr = this->_Bx._Ptr;
        this->_Getal().destroy(&this->_Bx._Ptr);
        if (0 < _Newsize)
            _Traits::copy(this->_Bx._Buf,
                _STD addressof(*_Ptr), _Newsize);
        this->_Getal().deallocate(_Ptr, this->_Myres + 1);
        }
    this->_Myres = this->_BUF_SIZE - 1;
    _Eos(_Newsize);
}
```

And my program executes a break at `this->_Getal().deallocate(_Ptr, this->_Myres + 1);`.

Here's the code for the gui:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include "gui.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> PartClasses;

gui::gui(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent){

    getPartClasses(PartClasses); //my own function, does not affect how the gui runs, just puts strings in PartClasses

    label1 = new QLabel(tr("Insert Name (Optional):"));
    label2 = new QLabel(tr("Class Name (Required):"));
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit;

    goButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Go"));
    goButton->setDefault(true);
    connect(goButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_go_clicked()));

    cb = new QComboBox();
    for(int i = 0; i < PartClasses.size(); i++)
        cb->addItem(QString::fromStdString(PartClasses[i]));

    //*add widgets to layouts, removed for space*

    setWindowTitle(tr("TEST"));
    setFixedHeight(sizeHint().height());
}

void gui::on_go_clicked(){
    std::string str(cb->currentText().toStdString());
    updateDB(str, lineEdit->text().toUtf8().constData()); //my function, does not affect the gui.
    QApplication::exit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    gui *stuff = new gui;
    stuff->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

What is it doing? When I'm done with the slot, shouldn't the gui just come back up, so that I can specify a new object? How can I get it to either not delete this object, or get it to succeed?

Comment: Sounds like you have a crash in your program that's completely unrelated to signals and slots

Comment: I just tried adding `QApplication::exit()` after the call to my function in `on_go_clicked()`, and it executes quit, but the gui doesn't close, and the program still breaks.

Comment: Chris, nothing should be happening in my program after the function runs. I wrote the gui without the functions, and it worked. I wrote the function without the gui, and it works. I put the function in the gui, and it calls the function, finishes, and returns to the gui, but then crashes when the slot function finishes.

Comment: If I comment out the `updateDB()` code, the application runs `QApplication::exit()` just fine, and quits. If I get rid of `QApplication::exit()`, there is no break. The issue is deleting temporary objects created in the function and used as arguments in the function... but why can't it delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best guess at what is happening:

An object that you are accessing is getting deleted somewhere where it shouldn't.

That `_Tidy` function looks like it is doing some cleanup after string manipulation.  Chances are the const-ness of your `char *` didn't make it down, and you are deleting a const pointer.

To fix this I would make a deep copy of your variable and pass that into your `updateDB` that does the `xstring` LaTex stuff.  Or you could create an xstring object right then and there and pass it down.

I would also consider using `strcpy` or something similar, or maybe just the `std::string`.

Also the crash code that comes out can be helpful, too.

EDIT:

Here is what your code should probably look like...

```
void gui::on_go_clicked(){
    std::string str(cb->currentText().toStdString());
    std::string line_edit_str(lineEdit->text().toUtf8().constData());

    updateDB(str, line_edit_str); //my function, does not affect the gui.
    QApplication::exit();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: For some reason it was because I used `toStdString()` instead of `.toUtf8().constData()`. I hate that it won't let me use the normal way for some reason.

Comment: QString is extremely powerful and can handle all the craziness of localization in UTF, Wide Character, and internet standards.  If you put the variable into a local scoped variable, you shouldn't have an issue, but if you pass in an immutable const element down, you are asking for trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495226/immutable-object-in-collections-c-and-qt