# Is there an error with my code to put data in map?

Tags: java, dictionary, put

I can't see the error of my code, I hope you can find it!

Language: Java
IDE: Eclipse

I've created an object.
This object contains this data:

```
public class ObjectTypeBean {
   private  Map<String, String> connectedOperators = new HashMap<String, String>();

   public Map<String, String> getConnectedOperators() {
       return connectedOperators;
   }

   public void setConnectedOperators(String operatorId, String label) {
       this.connectedOperators.put(operatorId, label);
    }
}
```

Then I've created a list of this object-class

```
List<ObjectTypeBean> name= new ArrayList<ObjectTypeBean>();
```

And I'm trying to add new Data to the map.
I'm trying it like this:

```
for(ObjectTypeBean n:name){
   n.setConnectedOperators("one", "two");
}
```

But as soon as I tun this I get a

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.base/java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
    at ObjectTypeBean.setConnectedOperators(ObjectTypeBean.java:356)
    at MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:372)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834).
```

Comment: What import did you use for `HashMap`? Can you provide the complete source of `ObjectTypeBean` including imports and package declaration?

Comment: ...and make sure you have that type on the classpath _exactly once_ - you may have an old one somewhere else: The error message only contains the class name, not its classloader (e.g. tomcat/lib, the global directory for tomcat which you seem to run)

Comment: The code you've posted works just fine for me. There has to be something wrong with parts you didn't post in here. You would get such exception if you'd create a `Collections.unmodifiableMap` somewhere.

Comment: Something tells me you are trying to mix Scala and Java here?

Comment: `import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;` I'm autogenerating a Builder in `ObjectTypeBean` as my actual object has 30+ Strings. The builder autogenerates the Map as `private Map<String, String> connectedOperators = Collections.emptyMap();`

Comment: On a sidenode: "name" doesn't seem like a good name for a collection, i'd expect a plural, e.g. "names".

Comment: [Collections.emptyMap() vs new HashMap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846920/collections-emptymap-vs-new-hashmap)

Comment: You can't put anything into a `Collections.emptyMap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your suggestions I found the answer!

The problem was, that I'm using a builder in my `ObjectTypeBean`-Object.
As the builder creates an `Collections.emptyMap()` so that the map can be empty.

I've removed the `connectedOperators`-Map from the builder and there is no error anymore.
Thankyou!

Comment: Next time you ask a question, include **all** the relevant code.

Comment: I had assumed that that was all the relevant code. Otherwise I would have done that. Its just that I have 30+ variables declared there and did not want to post all of them.