# Java constructor with Guice injected fields along with non-injected fields

Tags: java, constructor, guice, code-injection

I have a class which has a constructor where all the arguments are injected by GUICE.

```
Public class Order {

    private final ClassOne classOneObj;
    private final ClassTwo classTwoObj;

    @Inject
    public order(ClassOne classOneObj, ClassTwo classTwoObj){
    this.classOneObj = classOneObj;
    this.classTwoObj = classTwoObj;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add one more field(say, int status)variable which can't be injected.

Is it a good practice to create an object first with all the injected parameters and then set the new field which can't be injected with a setter method?

I came up with another approach where I created a factory class as given below:

```
public class OrderFactory {

    private final ClassOne classOneObj;
    private final ClassTwo classTwoObj;

    @Inject
    public order(ClassOne classOneObj, ClassTwo classTwoObj){
    this.classOneObj = classOneObj;
    this.classTwoObj = classTwoObj;
    }

   //getter methods for all the above variables

    public  ClassOne getclassOneObj(){
          return classOneObj;
    }
    ....

    public Order createOrder(int status) {
        return new Order(status, classOneObj, classTwoObj);
    }
}
```

Then the new Order class will look like

```
public class Order {

    int status
    private final ClassOne classOneObj;
    private final ClassTwo classTwoObj;


    public order(int status, ClassOne classOneObj, ClassTwo classTwoObj){
    this.status = status
    this.classOneObj = classOneObj;
    this.classTwoObj = classTwoObj;
    }

    //getter methods for all these member variables
}
```

Now to create the order object I will first create an OrderFactory object and then using the "createOrder" method I will create the Order object.

I am ending up with writing boilerplate code. Not sure if this is a good practice. Can anybody suggest on this if this approach is correct or there is any better approach for this problem?

I read in Google Guice and found there is a feature @Assisted for assisted injection for such cases. But I found that complex and couldn't convince myself whether I should go with that in my case.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or guidance.

Comment: Echoing iluxa, your manual approach to factories is fine, though you can make assisted injection work in a much shorter fashion. The only thing I would change about your manual injection is to inject a `Provder<ClassOne>` and `Provider<ClassTwo>` instead, if you want to create many different Orders with the same OrderFactory. Otherwise, it looks great.

Answer (score 4):

Your factory approach is excellent. Please don't use the setters: if the field can be made immutable, it should be immutable, whether or not it makes it "convenient" to instantiate.

Another approach you can take is [Assisted Injection](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject), which solves this exact problem. With that, you only define the factory interface, and its implementation is magically given to you by Guice:

```
class Order {
  interface Factory {
    Order create(Status status);
  }

  @AssistedInject Order(
      ClassOne one, 
      ClassTwo two, 
      @Assisted Status status) {
  }
}
```

Module code:

```
bind(Order.Factory.class).toProvider(
    FactoryProvider.newFactory(Order.Factory.class, Order.class));
```

Then the clients inject `Factory` and use it just like they do in your example.

Answer (score -1):

You're typically going to inject things that take some amount of effort to construct. If you're just injecting an int field, you'd be better off just calling a setter method on the object (that has some of it's more complex dependencies injected). Also, if a fields changes frequently, as implied by a field called "status", then it's also not a good candidate for injection.

Comment: Please avoid setters whenever possible. If there's any chance to keep the object immutable and all its fields `final`, do that.

Comment: +1 to iluxa. Immutable objects have [a lot of benefits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/214718/1426891). We all agree that injecting `status` is a bad idea, but the OP's question was about letting injection coexist with _non-injected_ constructor arguments, for which there are many valid use-cases.

Comment: Yeah, working for Google teaches you a thing or two about guice doesn't it... :-)

Comment: I agree immutability especially with respect to multi threading is best. In his use case, a field called "status" seems to indicate  volatility, maybe it's not (especially if he's providing a factory for it). If that field never changes, sure inject it. If it does, you want to create a new one each time? int assignment is atomic, make it volatile and you're good to go.