# Should all value objects be immutable

Tags: php, oop, domain-driven-design

I have 1 `Employee` entity which holds a value object of `ContactInformation` :

**Employee.php**

```
class Employee {
    private $contactInformation;

    public function __construct(ContactInformation $contactInformation) {
        $this->contactInformation = $contactInformation;
    }

    public function getContactInformation() {
        return $this->contactInformation;
    }
}
```

**ContactInformation.php**

```
class ContactInformation {
    private $email;        // Required
    private $cellPhone;    // Required
    private $phone;        // Optional
    private $address;      // Optional

    public function __construct($email, $cellPhone) {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->cellphone = $cellphone;
    }

    /** Here goes a bunch of setter getter for those properties **/
}
```

If an Employee's phone is changed, is it not better to do just

> $employee->getContactInformation()->setPhone($newPhone)

Rather than forcing immutability such as

> $employee->setContactInformation(new ContactInformation(/** copy paste
>   here **/));

Going by Eric Evans' book, I understand that when you change a part of a value object, then it is a whole different value object then it was before.

I just cannot get the same conclusion about a little bit more complex object like this ContactInformation, is it supposed to be an Entity?

Need advice, thanks !

Comment: I would go for the first approach, there will be rarely case that second is better.

Comment: @RoyalBg So have I, but I just can't get rid this icky feeling about how ContactInformation should be treated as an Entity

Comment: Why didn't you extend Employee with ContactInformation and allow $employee->setPhone()?

Comment: @VincentNikkelen That sounds kind of weird.. It's almost like saying that Employee is a ContactInformation to me

Comment: @SamuelAdam for me it's better that Employee to not have dependency of contact information but vice versa. You cannot have contact information alone, because it should be bound to a certain employee

Comment: @SamuelAdam Can agree with you on 'weird', it all depends on if you expect to use ContactInformation as an object not associated with Employee. Btw, check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects?rq=1 I agree that you should only worry about your choice when you have concurrency in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, Employee to have dependency on `ContactInformation` means that you expect to have `ContactInformation` already set with phones, etc. and then passed to employee, i.e.:

```
$contanctInfo = new ContactInformation();
$contanctInfo->setPhone(820);
$employee1 = new Employee($contanctInfo);
echo $employee1->getContanctInformation()->getPhone(); // 820
```

However, that means you would need to make as much ContactInformation objects, as Employee objects, before instantiating each Employee, because:

```
$contanctInfo = new ContactInformation();
$contanctInfo->setPhone(820);
$employee1 = new Employee($contanctInfo);
$employee2 = new Employee($contanctInfo);
$employee1->getContactInformation()->setPhone(123);
$employee2->getContactInformation()->setPhone(666);

echo $employee1->getContactInformation()->getPhone();
echo $employee2->getContactInformation()->getPhone();
```

Turns into:

```
666
666
```

Because you are changing one and the same object.

In your case, you are instantiating `ContactInformation` at the same time, when you are instantiating `Employee` when makes the dependency a bit useless:

```
$employee1 = new Employee(new ContactInformation());
$employee2 = new Employee(new ContactInformation());

$employee1->getContactInformation()->setPhone(123);
$employee2->getContactInformation()->setPhone(666);

echo $employee1->getContactInformation()->getPhone();
echo $employee2->getContactInformation()->getPhone();
```

Results into:

```
123
666
```

So, if you don't want to make changes on the dependent object before inject it to another object, you don't need a dependency at all. Even more, in real world `ContanctInformation` is bind to an `Employee`, not the opposite.

I would make it this way:

```
class Employee {

    private $_contactInformation;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_contactInformation = new ContactInformation($this);
    }

    /**
     * @return ContactInformation
     */
    public function getContactInformation() {
        return $this->_contactInformation;
    }
}

class ContactInformation {

    private $_employee;

    private $email;        // Required
    private $cellPhone;    // Required
    private $phone;        // Optional
    private $address;      // Optional

    public function __construct(Employee $employee) {
        $this->_employee = $employee;
    }

    public function setPhone($phone) {
        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    public function getPhone() {
        return $this->phone;
    }
}

$employee1 = new Employee();
$employee2 = new Employee();

$employee1->getContactInformation()->setPhone(123);
$employee2->getContanctInformation()->setPhone(666);

echo $employee1->getContactInformation()->getPhone();
echo $employee2->getContactInformation()->getPhone();
```

On the other hand, if Employee has some identificator, so the `ContanctInfo` retrieves info based on the ID, you can make the injection the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, it does good to have another pair of eyes

Answer (score 1):

Value objects should be immutable, but `ContactInformation` should not be a value object.

Consider two people who share a house, and therefore have the same address and phone number (it simplifies matters if you assume they don't have a cellular phone or email).

In that situation, they'd have identical `ContactInformation` objects, but the contact information is still distinctly one person's or another's. If one of them moves out, or buys a cell phone then their contact information will have to change.

As you mentioned in your comment, it's better to consider `ContactInformation` as a mutable Entity, and not a Value Object.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting discussion.  What I do is to have getContactInformation return a clone.

```
class Employee {

public function getContactInformation() {
    return clone $this->contactInformation;
}
...
$contactInformation = $employee->getContactInformation();
$contactInformation->setPhone('');
$employee->setContactInformation($contactInformation);
```

By doing so, the value object actually stored inside of Employee is immutable.  You always pull a copy, which since it no longer linked to employee, is no longer a value object(one could argue with lots of hand waving) and thus can be modified without upsetting the DDD police.

Works for me and let's me use a form system which expects setters.