# How exactly does the "let" keyword work in Swift?

Tags: constants, swift

I've read this simple explanation in the guide:

> The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once.

But I want a little more detail than this. If the constant references an object, can I still modify its properties? If it references a collection, can I add or remove elements from it? I come from a C# background; is it similar to how `readonly` works (apart from being able to use it in method bodies), and if it's not, how is it different?

Comment: It seems to mean that you can not change the var, but if the var points to an object you should deb able to make changes to the object in the same manner as objects accesses in the scope of a block. IOW, it a var points to a mutable array the values in the array should be able to be changed.

Comment: If you're coming from C#, then it would have the same meaning as "readonly var", if that was allowed. Or "let" in F#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`let\` and \`var\` in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

Comment: Yes you can still modify the properties, dependending on how they were configured. This works similarly to `const` in JavaScript. A field can generally still be modified unless it was frozen/sealed or marked as non-writable.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`let` is a little bit like a `const` pointer in C. If you reference an object with a `let`, you can change the object's properties or call methods on it, but you cannot assign a different object to that identifier.

`let` also has implications for collections and  non-object types. If you reference a `struct` with a `let`, you cannot change its properties or call any of its `mutating func` methods.

Using `let`/`var` with collections works much like mutable/immutable Foundation collections: If you assign an array to a `let`, you can't change its contents. If you reference a dictionary with `let`, you can't add/remove key/value pairs or assign a new value for a key — it's truly immutable. If you want to assign to subscripts in, append to, or otherwise mutate an array or dictionary,  you must declare it with `var`.

(Prior to Xcode 6 beta 3, Swift arrays had a weird mix of value and reference semantics, and were partially mutable when assigned to a `let` -- that's gone now.)

Comment: do you know if the behavior is consistent with `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary` ?

Comment: consistent in what way?

Comment: well… I guess I should have asked: are there any notable inconsistencies? (performance, methods, etc)

Comment: That's peculiar, you can change array defined with let, but you cannot change dictionary defined with let.

Comment: Update: From XCode 6 beta 3 onwards, you also cannot substitute values in arrays defined with let, so it seems more consistent now.

Source: https://functionwhatwhat.com/breaking-changes-to-swift-in-xcode-6-beta-3/#newvaluesemanticsforarrays

Comment: Thank you for the analogy between 'let' and the C 'const pointer', that's helpful.

Answer (score 5):

It's best to think of `let` in terms of *Static Single Assignment* (SSA) -- every SSA variable is assigned to *exactly* once. In functional languages like lisp you don't (normally) use an assignment operator -- names are bound to a value exactly once. For example, the names `y` and `z` below are bound to a value exactly once (per invocation):

```
func pow(x: Float, n : Int) -> Float {
  if n == 0 {return 1}
  if n == 1 {return x}
  let y = pow(x, n/2)
  let z = y*y
  if n & 1 == 0 {
    return z
  }
  return z*x
}
```

This lends itself to more correct code since it enforces invariance and is side-effect free.

Here is how an imperative-style programmer might compute the first 6 powers of 5:

```
var powersOfFive = Int[]()
for n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] {
    var n2 = n*n
    powersOfFive += n2*n2*n
}
```

Obviously `n2` is is a loop invariant so we could use `let` instead:

```
var powersOfFive = Int[]()
for n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] {
    let n2 = n*n
    powersOfFive += n2*n2*n
}
```

But a truly functional programmer would avoid all the side-effects and mutations:

```
let powersOfFive = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(
    {(num: Int) -> Int in
        let num2 = num*num
        return num2*num2*num})
```

Comment: Lisp definitely has assignment, and values can be assigned to a variable many times.

Comment: Yes Lisp certainly does allow assignment ( eg setf), but functional programmers only use it when it's truly necessary... which does happen.

Answer (score 4):

#### *Let*

---

Swift uses two basic techniques to store values for a programmer to access by using a name:  *let* and *var*.  Use *let* if you're never going to change the value associated with that name.  Use *var* if you expect for that name to refer to a changing set of values.

```
let a = 5  // This is now a constant. "a" can never be changed.
var b = 2  // This is now a variable. Change "b" when you like.
```

The value that a constant refers to can never be changed, however the thing that a constant refers to can change if it is an instance of a class.

```
let a = 5
let b = someClass()
a = 6  // Nope.
b = someOtherClass()  // Nope.
b.setCookies( newNumberOfCookies: 5 )  // Ok, sure.
```

#### *Let* and Collections

---

When you assign an array to a constant, elements can no longer be added or removed from that array.  However, the value of any of that array's elements may still be changed.

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
a.append(4)  // This is NOT OK. You may not add a new value.
a[0] = 0     // This is OK. You can change an existing value.
```

A dictionary assigned to a constant can not be changed in any way.

```
let a = [1: "Awesome", 2: "Not Awesome"]
a[3] = "Bogus"             // This is NOT OK. You may not add new key:value pairs.
a[1] = "Totally Awesome"   // This is NOT OK. You may not change a value.
```

---

That is my understanding of this topic.  Please correct me where needed.  Excuse me if the question is already answered, I am doing this in part to help myself learn.

Comment: Sorry but I think your example of _Let and Collections_ with the array example is incorrect as, mutability is not allowed for `a[0] = 0`, so this is NOT OK.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **"The let keyword defines a constant"** is confusing for beginners who are coming from C# background (like me). After reading many Stack Overflow answers, I came to the conclusion that

> **Actually, in swift there is no concept of constant**

A constant is an expression that is resolved at compilation time. For both C# and Java, constants must be assigned during declaration:

```
public const double pi = 3.1416;         // C#
public static final double pi = 3.1416   // Java
```

Apple doc ( defining constant using "let" ):

> The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign the value exactly once.

**In C# terms, you can think of "let" as `"readonly"` variable**

> Swift "let" == C# "readonly"

Answer (score 0):

F# users will feel right at home with Swift's let keyword. :)

In C# terms, you can think of "let" as "readonly var", if that construct was allowed, i.e.: an identifier that can only be bound at the point of declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Swift properties:

[Swift Properties official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

> In its simplest form, a stored property is a constant or variable that is stored as part of an instance of a particular class or structure. Stored properties can be either variable stored properties (introduced by the `var`keyword) or constant stored properties (introduced by the `let` keyword).

Example:

> The example below defines a structure called FixedLengthRange, which describes a range of integers whose range length cannot be changed once it is created:

```
struct FixedLengthRange {
    var firstValue: Int
    let length: Int
}
```

> Instances of `FixedLengthRange` have a variable stored property called `firstValue` and a constant stored property called `length`. In the example above, `length` is initialized when the new range is created and **cannot be changed thereafter, because it is a constant property**.