# What does 'let' in swift mean?

Tags: swift, constants, let

I'm learning swift, but i'm not a native english speaker and just want to ask what does 'let' mean? I know its a constant but then why it's not 'cons'?
Is 'let' an abbrevation of some word? 
I won't die without knowing it, i'm just curious ;)
Thanks.

Comment: Already described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002999/how-exactly-let-keyword-works-in-swift

Comment: let is itself an English word. Not abbreviated.

Comment: @gagarwal No, he's not asking how it's used, he's asking what the term itself means in a foreign language (English).

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let#Etymology_1

Comment: Note that in @famousgarkin's etymology link, case 6 is the point of interest.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's about the vagaries of the English language and not programming.

Answer (score 22):

There are other languages where `let` is used as a keyword before a variable declaration, such as BASIC and LISP (or Scheme), and I presume it was taken from there. It's not an abbreviation; it's the normal English word "let", used to introduce a command, as in "Let there be light;" in mathematics it is common to announce a symbol this way, as in "Let `x` be the unknown number of years we are trying to calculate."

To answer your question a little more fully, though: in my view, there is *nothing* about this word that makes it particularly suitable for constants. They seems to have made an arbitrary choice. `var` makes sense for a "variable" that *can vary* (get it?), so now they just needed another word, and they picked `let`. Personally, I think `const` *would* have been better.

Comment: However, at that point we have sunk into the realm of opinion and guesswork, which is not a suitable topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: My guess is actually that it stems from the functional/haskell background of swift, where "=" in a declaration is pronounced "is" or "be", similar to pascal and meta languages which use <- or := as pronounced "becomes"  Fundamental to functional programming is the lack of variables, instead only having constants, hence "let" is a normal constant expression.  "var" denotes an exception to the declaration rules allow modification.  "let a = 10" is then pronounced "let b be 10" and it makes sense.

Comment: @David Thanks, I wondered if it might be some language I didn't know (though my mention of LISP, which is purely functional as you can get, does cover it).

Comment: Yeah, the usage at that point is really very similar to the math usage of the term.