# Swift updating property of an object in Array, doesn't work

Tags: arrays, swift

I trying to update property of an object in an array and it doesn't work. 
I tried replacing the whole object in the array, but it didn't help

```
let object = myArray[0]
object.property = "new value"
myArray[0] = object
print(object.property) //"new value"

let sameObject = myArray[0]
print(sameObject.property) //"old value"
```

EDIT:
I found it!!! The array was singelton property. I was calling MyClass().myArray, instead of calling MyClass.sharedInstance.myArray

Comment: Have you tried: `myArray[0].property = "new Value"` ?

Comment: I just copied your code into a playground and it is working fine. The value is updated and the `secondObject.property` is `"new value"`.

Comment: Your code [works in a Playground](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxKMo-vdbVFkJezcXvFJAoYP4GDWz3I6hs).

Comment: @sasquatch, I tried it the first thing. But the value was not saved

Comment: @Adam, I simplified the code t=for the question. I'll update my question with the original code

Comment: @Eric D., I simplified the code t=for the question. I'll update my question with the original code

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `myArray`?

Comment: I found it!!! The array was singelton property. I was calling MyClass(). myArray, instead of calling MyClass.sharedInstance.myArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!!! The array was singelton property. I was calling MyClass(). myArray, instead of calling MyClass.sharedInstance.myArray

Answer (score 5):

This depends on what it is in the array. If its a class it will be a reference to the instance. If it is a struct, you will get a copy of it when you assign, leading to the changes you made to the copy not being applied to the object.

What is in the array?

Comment: I found it!!! The array was singelton property. I was calling MyClass(). myArray, instead of calling MyClass.sharedInstance.myArray

Answer (score 0):

I think is because you are declaring the array `let`: it means that it will remain unchanged. Try to declare it as `var` and then it should work.

**EDIT**
You are right, I think I misunderstood your question then; but i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24003328/2064585) that can be useful; at the end you should declare it `var`.

Comment: `object` is not being changed. There is no need to declare it as `var`

Comment: I found it!!! The array was singelton property. I was calling MyClass(). myArray, instead of calling MyClass.sharedInstance.myArray