# What is the use of "static" keyword if "let" keyword used to define constants/immutables in swift?

Tags: swift, static, constants

I'm little bit confused about using **static** keyword in swift. As we know swift introduces **let** keyword to declare immutable objects. Like declaring the id of a table view cell which most likely won't change during its lifetime. Now what is the use of **static** keyword in some declaration of struct like:

```
struct classConstants
{
    static let test = "test"
    static var totalCount = 0
}
```

whereas **let** keyword do the same.In Objective C we used static to declare some constant like

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellId";
```

Besides which makes me more curious is the use of **static** keyword along with **let** and also **var** keyword. Can anybody explain me where to use this static keyword? More importantly do we really need **static** in swift?

Comment: If you don't know what static is, I'd recommend you reading some OOP book before starting writing in swift. static variable is shared between all instances of an object, if it's const (let) then it is just immutable

Comment: @DanielKrom : As per my understanding, I used static to declare some constants in C, Objective C. I don't have a knowledge beyond that. So, I thought **let** and **static** are the same.

Comment: in C and Objective-C statics are not constants (unless you define them as constants), you probably didn't understand that well and it's fine, no one is born with knowledge, statics are kind of global variables

Comment: static define a type property: “Type Properties
Instance properties are properties that belong to an instance of a particular type. Every time you create a new instance of that type, it has its own set of property values, separate from any other instance.

You can also define properties that belong to the type itself, not to any one instance of that type. There will only ever be one copy of these properties, no matter how many instances of that type you create. These kinds of properties are called type properties.”
“The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3)”.

Comment: It's a good question. When the instance property's value is fully known at compile time (e.g. let = "hello, world") then a reasonable question occurs: why use a static property over an instance property? One assumes the compiler is smart enough to optimise away repeat values. And a static property incurs a slight inconvenience factor (having to include the type namespacing before using the property).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

I will break them down for you:

- `var` : used to create a variable
- `let` : used to create a constant
- `static` : used to create [type properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Type-Properties) with either `let` or `var`. These are shared between all objects of a class.

Now you can combine to get the desired out come:

- `static let key = "API_KEY"` : type property that is constant
- `static var cnt = 0` : type property that is a variable
- `let id = 0` : constant (can be assigned only once, but can be assigned at run time)
- `var price = 0` : variable

So to sum everything up var and let define mutability while static and lack of define scope. You might use `static var` to keep track of how many instances you have created, while you might want to use just `var`for a price that is different from object to object. Hope this clears things up a bit.

Example Code:

```
class MyClass{
    static let typeProperty = "API_KEY"
    static var instancesOfMyClass = 0
    var price = 9.99
    let id = 5

}

let obj = MyClass()
obj.price // 9.99
obj.id // 5

MyClass.typeProperty // "API_KEY"
MyClass.instancesOfMyClass // 0
```

Comment: "`let` : used to create a constant" => variable declared with `let` keyword can be assigned (only once) later (i.e. in constructor) which is contradictory to the definition of CONSTANT. If we compare with other languages such as C# then `let` is same as C# `readonly` (not `const`)

Comment: what is equivalent to `static let` in objective c because I have to define the uiaplicationdidenterbackground in view controller

Comment: Although I believe its technically correct you never gave an example of why I would ever need static over let.

Comment: To be more clear, a static var will have the same value in every instances of a class while a var will be a unique variable in each class.

Answer (score 130):

A static variable is shared through all instances of a class. Throw this example in playground:

```
class Vehicle {
    var car = "Lexus"
    static var suv = "Jeep"
}

// changing nonstatic variable
Vehicle().car // Lexus
Vehicle().car = "Mercedes"
Vehicle().car // Lexus

// changing static variable
Vehicle.suv // Jeep
Vehicle.suv = "Hummer"
Vehicle.suv // Hummer
```

When you change the variable for the static property, that property is now changed in all future instances.

Comment: Vehicle().car, giving **Lexus** , but, let vehObj = Vehicle(); vehObj.car, giving **Mercedes** . I don't know why. Whats the diff? Can u Guide me?

Comment: vehObj.car is giving me Lexus, I don't know why you're getting Mercedes

Comment: Let suv = Vehicle(); suv.suv // Jeep; let suv2 = Vehicle(); suv2.suv = "Hummer"; let suv3 = Vehicle(); suv3.suv // Hummer; If I then go "suv.suv" will it return "Jeep" or "Hummer"? Does the value change for all instances of that object, or just future instances? If it only changes for future instances, why is that? Why not all instances? Sorry if this is a stupid question. I guess I've not seen much application of static variables.

Answer (score 13):

Static Variables are belong to a type rather than to instance of class. You can access the static variable by using the full name of the type.

Code:

```
class IOS {

  var iosStoredTypeProperty = "iOS Developer"

  static var swiftStoredTypeProperty = "Swift Developer"

 }

 //Access the iosStoredTypeProperty by way of creating instance of IOS Class

let iOSObj = IOS()

print(iOSObj.iosStoredTypeProperty)  // iOS Developer


 //print(iOSObj.swiftStoredTypeProperty) 
 //Xcode shows the error 
 //"static member 'swiftStoredTypeProperty' cannot be used on instance of type IOS”


 //You can access the static property by using full name of the type
print(IOS.swiftStoredTypeProperty)  // Swift Developer
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 1):

to see the difference between type properties and / or methods and class properties and / or methods, please look at this self explanatory example from apple docs

```
class SomeClass {
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
    static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
        return 27
    }
    class var overrideableComputedTypeProperty: Int {
        return 107
    }
}
```

Static properties may only be declared on type, not globally. In other words static property === type property in Swift. To declare type property you have to use static keyword.

Comment: You are explaining static by using static itself. The OP isn't reallly aware of its meaning...

Comment: @asma22 ?? Keyword static has totally different meaning in swift and c language. Static in swift means 'type' (property or function). The difference between 'static' and 'class' property or function is that 'class' property or function could be overridden, 'static' could not be owerriden. Because most people with background use 'static' in other context, apple commensing to use 'type' word for explanation, even though the keyword is 'static'

Answer (score 1):

**"The let keyword defines a constant"** is confusing for beginners who are coming from C# background (like me). **In C# terms, you can think of "let" as "readonly" variable**.

(answer to [How exactly does the “let” keyword work in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166642/4802664))

Use both `static` and `let` to define constant

```
public static let pi = 3.1416            // swift

public const double pi = 3.1416;         // C#
public static final double pi = 3.1416   // Java
```

Whenever I use `let` to define constant, it feels like I am using `readonly` of C#. So, I use both `static` and `let` to define constant in swift.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain it for those who need Objective-C reference.

Hope you all remember that we were using a constant file in our Objective-C project to keep all the static API keys like below.

```
/ In your *.m file
static NSString * const kNSStringConst = @"const value";
```

Here the keyword **Static** does not mean that the **kNSStringConst** is a constant, it just defines that the **kNSStringConst** can be accessed globally. They keyword **const** makes it constant.

Now let's move to Swift.

In Swift, **Static let** and **Static var** are considered as **Type Properties**, which means that they can be accessed by their type.

For Example:

```
class World {
   static let largestPopulation = "China"
   static var secondLargestPopulation = "India"
}

World.largestPopulation = "German"   // Cannot assign to property: 'largestPopulation' is a 'let' constant
World.secondLargestPopulation = "UK"
World.secondLargestPopulation // UK
```

In this example, two properties have static keyword, one is constant and another one is variable.

1. As you can see, the constant **Static let** declared can be accessed by it's type, but cannot be
   changed.
2. The **Static var** declared can not only be accessed by it's type but also can be modified. Consequently, all the future instances will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

[[Swift's property]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60913330/4770877)
[[var vs let]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219124/4770877) 
[[class vs static]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236762/4770877)

In a nutshell `class` and `static` are type property and belongs to Type in a single copy