# Convert Int to String in Swift

Tags: string, casting, int, converters, swift

I'm trying to work out how to cast an `Int` into a `String` in Swift.

I figure out a workaround, using `NSNumber` but I'd love to figure out how to do it all in Swift.

```
let x : Int = 45
let xNSNumber = x as NSNumber
let xString : String = xNSNumber.stringValue
```

Answer (score 1124, accepted):

Converting `Int` to `String`:

```
let x : Int = 42
var myString = String(x)
```

And the other way around - converting `String` to `Int`:

```
let myString : String = "42"
let x: Int? = myString.toInt()

if (x != nil) {
    // Successfully converted String to Int
}
```

Or if you're using Swift 2 or 3:

```
let x: Int? = Int(myString)
```

Comment: While this works, use the `toString` function, shown in an answer below.

Comment: `Int` doesn't appear to have a `toString()` method at least not in Xcode 6.2                 edit: I see that there is a global `toString` method (***not*** `Int.toString()`), anyone know the advantage over using the `String()` constructor?

Comment: Note that `String(Int?)` writes "Optional(Int)", at least in Swift 2, that could not be what you meant. Use instead `Int?.description`

Comment: Wonderful, but doesn't work for me. I have an optional Int, and String(myInt) wont compile - it claims "Int? cannot be converted to String". There are no toString() or toInt() methods available for me either, or stringValue and intValue not there. Even a String(myInt!) will tell me that the initializer has been renamed to something like String(describing: myInt!).

Comment: For Swift 4, see Hamed Gh's answer below. The correct usage is `String(describing: x)`

Answer (score 99):

Check the Below Answer:

```
let x : Int = 45
var stringValue = "\(x)"
print(stringValue)
```

Comment: meh, this is an ugly and unnecessary workaround when `String` already has a constructor accepting `Int`

Comment: what wrong you find this? why you put down vote? @GabrielePetronella

Comment: I don't think this is particularly ugly, except that some parsing tools may not handle string interpolation nicely. Otherwise, who knows -- it might faster. Using ""+x in Javascript is generally faster than using a String constructor, for example.
This example is only a couple of characters shorter, but I would certainly prefer string interpolation in cases where you were constructing a sentence from several variables.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote this answer just because its ugly but as @GabrielePetronella said, there's no need to use string interpolation when `String` has a constructor that accepts an `Int`. Its much more clear and concise.

Comment: String(varName) didn't work for me for NSIndexPath, but the above syntax worked.

Comment: How is this uglier than array literals?

Comment: Well the other ways are much uglier - now my only way is String(describing: myInt!). if that's not ugly... what is???

Answer (score 69):

Here are 4 methods:

```
var x = 34
var s = String(x)
var ss = "\(x)"
var sss = toString(x)
var ssss = x.description
```

I can imagine that some people will have an issue with ss.  But if you were looking to build a string containing other content then why not.

Comment: I just watch some of the  Stanford U new course on Swift and iOS 8. Your `var ss = "\(x)"` example is exactly how they advised converting a double to a string.   Which I thought was easy and great.

Comment: And thinking more about sass - that's really bad.

Comment: toString has been renamed to String

Comment: s is now (Swift 3.1) String(describing: x) the older syntax yields compiler error.

Comment: @MottiShneor No, this is wrong. `String(describing:)` should never be used for anything else than debugging. It is not the normal String initializer.

Answer (score 55):

**In Swift 3.0**:

```
var value: Int = 10
var string = String(describing: value)
```

Comment: This is wrong. `String(describing:)` should never be used for anything else than debugging. It is not the normal String initializer.

Comment: Is this still wrong in Swift 5? @ayaio, cause basing from documentation it doesn't seem wrong

Comment: I would imagine so? it shouldn't be used for banch of different reasons, though, like for veing much too powerful for task on hands

Answer (score 33):

**Swift 4**:

```
let x:Int = 45
let str:String = String(describing: x)
```

[Developer.Apple.com > String > init(describing:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init)

> The String(describing:) initializer is the preferred way to convert an instance of any type to a string.

[Custom String Convertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

[image]

Comment: result Optional(1)

Comment: This is wrong. `String(describing:)` should never be used for anything else than debugging. It is not the normal String initializer.

Comment: @Moritz Could you provide a reference, please?

Comment: @Harshil Its depends on your input 'x'

Comment: Hamed Gh,  Morithz already provide right answer in same question check my answer Just use the normal String() initializer. But don't give it an optional, unwrap first. Or, like in your example, use ??. Like this: let str = String(x ?? 0)

Comment: @HamedGh Look at the examples in the link you give yourself. The `describing` method is here to... **describe** its content. It gives a description. Sometimes it's the same as the conversion, *sometimes not*. Give an optional to `describing` and you'll see the result... It will not be a conversion. There's a simple, dedicated way to convert: using the normal String initializer, as explained in other answers. Read the complete page that you link to: see that this method searches for *descriptions* using different ways, some of which would give wrong results if you expect accurate conversion..

Comment: @HamedGh I'm not here to say you're wrong for the pleasure of doing it. But I care about an answer that is wrong and which gives wrong example to beginners and users. Having 20 upvotes on this means that at least 20 people now wrongly believe that `describing` is the correct way to convert, because of you. This is not ok.  :(

Comment: You really should remove the describing part of this answer. Conversion should be done without using any parameter name in the String constructor.

Comment: @TimTwoToes you should really mention your resource. As I quote "The String(describing:) initializer is the preferred way to convert an instance of any type to a string."

Answer (score 31):

Just for completeness, you can also use:

```
let x = 10.description
```

or any other value that supports a description.

Comment: This worked for me when trying to show the value in a label.
With the other approaches it was always Optional(0) instead of 0.
Thank you

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4:**

Trying to show the value in label without **Optional()** word.

here x is a Int value using.

```
let str:String = String(x ?? 0)
```

Comment: No. `String(describing:)` should never be used for anything else than debugging. It is not the normal String initializer.

Comment: Hello @Moritz so what can i do for remove optional word ?
i have a Int value and than i want to print in label

Comment: Just use the normal `String()` initializer. But don't give it an optional, unwrap first. Or, like in your example, use `??`. Like this: `let str = String(x ?? 0)`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init

i understand your point what is the use of describing

Comment: It's mostly for debugging purposes. You can describe the name of classes, get the description of instances, etc. But it should never be used for strings that are used in the app itself.

Answer (score 10):

To save yourself time and hassle in the future you can make an Int extension.  Typically I create a shared code file where I put extensions, enums, and other fun stuff.  Here is what the extension code looks like:

```
extension Int
{
    func toString() -> String
    {
        var myString = String(self)
        return myString
    }
}
```

Then later when you want to convert an int to a string you can just do something like:

```
var myNumber = 0
var myNumberAsString = myNumber.toString()
```

Comment: Potentially stupid question, but should this be a function, or a computed variable? I can't recall which one Swift normally uses in these cases - is it `toInt` or `toInt()`.

Comment: To save yourself some time and hassle just use `myNumber.description`. No need for any extensions.

Answer (score 10):

in **swift 3.0** this is how we can convert `Int` to `String` and `String` to `Int`

```
//convert Integer to String in Swift 3.0

let theIntegerValue :Int = 123  // this can be var also
let theStringValue :String = String(theIntegerValue)


//convert String to Integere in Swift 3.0


let stringValue : String = "123"
let integerValue : Int = Int(stringValue)!
```

Comment: In the last line of the code, why do we need an exclamation mark at the end?

Comment: @OmarTariq, because we explicitly tells the compiler that the `integerValue`'s type is `Int`. then cannot have a nil  value for it. so compiler tells you to unwrap it. if you want to avoid this , use it like `let integerValue = Int(stringValue)`. then you won't get a problem. sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @OmarTariq Unwrapping in this case can be really bad. If the string isn't a number this will crash your application. You should really check to ensure that is valid and not force unwrap it.

Answer (score 8):

for whatever reason the accepted answer did not work for me. I went with this approach:

```
var myInt:Int = 10
var myString:String = toString(myInt)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
let intAsString = 45.description     // "45"
let stringAsInt = Int("45")          // 45
```

Answer (score 6):

Multiple ways to do this :

```
var str1:String="\(23)"
var str2:String=String(format:"%d",234)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift String performance**

A little bit about performance
`UI Testing Bundle` on iPhone 7(real device) with iOS 14

```
let i = 0
lt result1 = String(i) //0.56s 5890kB
lt result2 = "\(i)" //0.624s 5900kB
lt result3 = i.description //0.758s 5890kB
```

```
import XCTest

class ConvertIntToStringTests: XCTestCase {
    let count = 1_000_000
    
    func measureFunction(_ block: () -> Void) {
        let metrics: [XCTMetric] = [
            XCTClockMetric(),
            XCTMemoryMetric()
        ]
        let measureOptions = XCTMeasureOptions.default
        measureOptions.iterationCount = 5
        
        measure(metrics: metrics, options: measureOptions) {
            block()
        }
    }

    func testIntToStringConstructor() {
        var result = ""
        measureFunction {
            for i in 0...count {
                result += String(i)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func testIntToStringInterpolation() {
        var result = ""
        measureFunction {
            for i in 0...count {
                result += "\(i)"
            }
        }
    }
    
    func testIntToStringDescription() {
        var result = ""
        measureFunction {
            for i in 0...count {
                result += i.description
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 2:

```
var num1 = 4
var numString = "56"
var sum2 = String(num1) + numString
var sum3 = Int(numString)
```

Answer (score 3):

iam using this simple approach

String to Int:

```
 var a = Int()
var string1 = String("1")
a = string1.toInt()
```

and from Int to String:

```
var a = Int()
a = 1
var string1 = String()
 string1= "\(a)"
```

Answer (score 3):

## Convert Unicode Int to String

For those who want to convert an Int to a Unicode string, you can do the following:

```
let myInteger: Int = 97

// convert Int to a valid UnicodeScalar
guard let myUnicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(myInteger) else {
    return ""
}

// convert UnicodeScalar to String
let myString = String(myUnicodeScalar)

// results
print(myString) // a
```

Or alternatively:

```
let myInteger: Int = 97
if let myUnicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(myInteger) {
    let myString = String(myUnicodeScalar)
}
```

Comment: @jvarela, This does still work. I just retested it in Xcode 8.2 (Swift 3.0.2). The `String` initializer can take a `UnicodeScalar`.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using [String Interpolation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html)

```
let x = 45
let string = "\(x)"
```

Each object has some string representation. This makes things simpler. For example if you need to create some `String` with multiple values. You can also do any math in it or use some conditions

```
let text = "\(count) \(count > 1 ? "items" : "item") in the cart. Sum: $\(sum + shippingPrice)"
```

Answer (score 2):

`exampleLabel.text = String(yourInt)`

Answer (score 2):

If you like swift extension, you can add following code

```
extension Int
{
    var string:String {
        get {
            return String(self)
        }
    }
}
```

then, you can get string by the method you just added

```
var x = 1234
var s = x.string
```

Answer (score 1):

**To convert String into Int**

```
var numberA = Int("10")

Print(numberA) // It will print 10
```

**To covert Int into String**

```
var numberA = 10
```

1st way)

```
print("numberA is \(numberA)") // It will print 10
```

2nd way)

```
var strSomeNumber = String(numberA)
```

or

```
var strSomeNumber = "\(numberA)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3.0, you may change integer to string as given below

```
let a:String = String(stringInterpolationSegment: 15)
```

Another way is

```
let number: Int = 15
let _numberInStringFormate: String = String(number)
```

//or any integer number in place of 15

Comment: From API reference "Do not call this initializer directly. It is used by the compiler when interpreting string interpolations." May be you want to double check if you are using it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
let a =123456888
var str = String(a)
```

OR

```
var str = a as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let Str = "12"
let num: Int = 0
num = Int (str)
```