# Swift and XCode 6 - Converting Integer to String

Tags: string, swift, casting, integer, int

I have an Xcode project with a label and a UIAction button. Upon tapping the button, I want the value displayed in the label to increase by 1. The problem is that I can't display the variable "value" in the label, because it's an integer, and the label takes a String data type. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var value = 0 

@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    value = value + 1
    label.text = value
}
```

Comment: value.description or string interpolation "\\(value)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Int to String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161336/convert-int-to-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 17):

```
label.text = String(value)
```

Or

```
label.text = "\(value)"
```

Or

```
label.text = value.description
```

Comment: Which do you use most? .description or String()

Comment: In Swift 3 ` String(describing: value)` is preferred

Comment: @LinhChu String(describing: ) may return "Optional(intValue)" as the string while .description does not

Answer (score 0):

Of course I would save some typing and express it this way:

```
value++ 
label.text = value.description
```

In the end it is the same thing as:

```
value = value + 1
label.text = value.description
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert value before saving core data directly just like that

```
//core data 
userid value = string
```

we need to store Int value we have to convert the value explicitly like that. I tried that and it works fine 
core data contain task entity having user_id attribute

```
 tasksEntity.user_id = string
```

that should work