# Unwrapping a Int to String cast in Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9

I am gathering an `NSNumber` from my plist and I want to print that in a `String`:

```
let tijd = String(self.sortedHighscores[indexPath.row]["Tijd"]!)
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(tijd) seconden"
```

But in Simulator I'm seeing printed: `Optional(120) seconden` for example.
How do I solve this? I've tried unwrapping `tijd`, but that would result in errors in the compiler telling me to delete the `!`.

Comment: first yo have to unwrap then convert into string
this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161336/convert-int-to-string-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var highscore : NSNumber =  self.sortedHighscores[indexPath.row]["Tijd"] as! NSNumber
 var a : String = String(format:"%d",highscore.integerValue)
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = a
```

Comment: A Swift String does not have the format initializer, according to my autocomplete?

Comment: That did not help, are you sure you didn't mean it to be `NSString`?

Comment: yes I am sure...just try to copy and paste and give it a try

Comment: I solved it like this:

`let tijd:NSNumber = self.sortedHighscores[indexPath.row]["Tijd"] as! NSNumber`
        `let tijdStr:String = NSString(format: "%d", tijd.integerValue) as String`

Answer (score -1):

`tijd` being an optional, you need to unwrap it, but you should check whether it has a value, too.

```
if let foo = tijd {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(foo) seconden"
}
```

If you know it will always have a value, `"\(tijd!) seconden"` should work also.