# Converting String in Integer in Swift

Tags: swift

I have written some code in Xcode and the error is on the last line. Can someone help me convert the string to an integer?

```
@IBAction func btnCalc(_ sender: Any) {
    let numb1 = Int(txtN1.text!)
    let numb2 = Int(txtN2.text!)

    let calcResult = (numb1)! + (numb2)!
    labelResult.text = (calcResult)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Int to String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161336/convert-int-to-string-in-swift)

Comment: you can use String interpolation, String initializer or get its description property value. `"\(calcResult)"` , `String(calcResult)` or `calcResult.description`

Comment: @LeoDabus Note the latter is discouraged by the Swift team.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the feedback !!! Do you have a link (reference) of it?

Comment: give us the link please

Comment: I could't find any note at the docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/int/1539460-description

Comment: @LeoDabus Oops sorry, I meant to add a link, but got sidetracked – the note is in the [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customstringconvertible) docs: "*Accessing a type’s `description` property directly or using `CustomStringConvertible` as a generic constraint is discouraged.*"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Int to String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161336/convert-int-to-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Int(myString)

Swift 1.x

```
let myString: String = "256" let myInt: Int? = myString.toInt()
```

Swift 2.x, 3.x

```
let myString: String = "256" let myInt: Int? = Int(myString)
```

Comment: Thank you my friend it's working