# Is there a way to convert "NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate" to a string like Firebase does?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create multiple node updates inside one `Database.database().reference().updateChildValues([AnyHashable: Any])` request, but in this array I need key values which are just like `childByAutoId()`.

I tried doing so by creating key nodes with the value of `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000;` but Firebase does not accept integer keys.

Is there a way to get the method of how Firebase creates these unique child nodes, which are time-sorted ID's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Int to String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161336/convert-int-to-string-in-swift)

Comment: Generally speaking (very generally), updateChildValues would be used when the node (key) is known so you know which node to update. The question sounds like you are creating nodes instead of updating them? Perhaps you can clarify the question and provide a snippet of  your structure (as text please) so we can understand what's being asked? Also, timestamps for keys may not be the best idea - but again, need to understand the use case.

Comment: @Jay I am updating an known node, but with an dictionary with some unknown nodes. I am just trying to get firebase's method of generating the `childByAutoId()` key.

Comment: Can you please include your Firebase structure? What do you propose it looks like? Also, can you post the code you've tried - `[AnyHashable: Any]` is too vague to understand the use case. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update the question and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
print(uuid)
```

Only create unique string