# How can I convert Int64 to String in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, int64

I want to convert the value of Int64 variable to String.
String(x) is not working here.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: Hi Sajib, I also think is a good idea to check out the link that Asperi provided in the comment before. 
But could you also please add some code that is not working. E.g. when I create a Int64 variable (var number) and I use it (String(number)) in a SwiftUI Text, in a print command or even in a new variable/constant (let intToNumber = String(number)), it works well for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Int to String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161336/convert-int-to-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

```
let number: Int64 = 64
let string: String = "\(number)"
print(string)
```

output

```
64
Program ended with exit code: 0
```