# Difference between "precondition" and "assert" in swift?

Tags: swift

What's the difference between `precondition(condition: Bool, message: String)` and `assert(condition: Bool, message: String)` in Swift?

Both of them look same to me. In which context should we use one over the other?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`assert` is for sanity checks during testing, whereas `precondition` is for guarding against things that, if they happen, would mean your program just could not reasonably proceed.

So for example, you might put an `assert` on some calculation having sensible results (within some bounds, say), to quickly find if you have a bug.  But you wouldn’t want to ship with that, since the out-of-bound result *might* be valid, and not critical so shouldn’t crash your app (suppose you were just using it to display progress in a progress bar).

On the other hand, checking that a subscript on an array is valid when fetching an element is a `precondition`.  There is no reasonable next action for the array object to take when asked for an invalid subscript, since it *must* return a non-optional value.

Full text from the docs (try option-clicking `assert` and `precondition` in Xcode):

**Precondition**

> Check a necessary condition for making forward progress.
>
> Use this function to detect conditions that must prevent the
>   program from proceeding even in shipping code.
>
> - In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode's Debug
>     configuration): if `condition` evaluates to false, stop program
>     execution in a debuggable state after printing `message`.
> - In -O builds (the default for Xcode's Release configuration):
>     if `condition` evaluates to false, stop program execution.
> - In -Ounchecked builds, `condition` is not evaluated, but the
>     optimizer may assume that it *would* evaluate to `true`. Failure
>     to satisfy that assumption in -Ounchecked builds is a serious
>     programming error.

**Assert**

> Traditional C-style assert with an optional message.
>
> Use this function for internal sanity checks that are active
>   during testing but do not impact performance of shipping code.
>   To check for invalid usage in Release builds; see `precondition`.
>
> - In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode's Debug
>     configuration): if `condition` evaluates to false, stop program
>     execution in a debuggable state after printing `message`.
> - In -O builds (the default for Xcode's Release configuration),
>     `condition` is not evaluated, and there are no effects.
> - In -Ounchecked builds, `condition` is not evaluated, but the
>     optimizer may assume that it *would* evaluate to `true`. Failure
>     to satisfy that assumption in -Ounchecked builds is a serious
>     programming error.

Comment: "But you wouldn’t want to ship with that, since the out-of-bound result *might* be valid, and not critical so shouldn’t crash your app" that's very vague to me. Kindly can you include an exact example? Perhaps some code.

Comment: Responding to your question, I personally use asserts to catch things that just shouldn't happen in my build while I am writing and testing it.  Imagine a guard statement reading JSON where `data["name"]` does not exist, but it should. Having an assert inside of the guard..else{} would help me catch my error by crashing and bringing me to the problem. Similarily, if this code was in production, the assert wouldn't crash the program, and whatever backup code that I used (`return nil`) would take over.

Comment: Shouldn't you check the index and not do anything instead of crashing the whole app?

Comment: Yes, you should check the index, but everyone slips up sometimes, and using asserts helps you to realize you should have checked the index when you forgot.

Comment: "But you wouldn’t want to ship with that, since the out-of-bound result might be valid, and not critical so shouldn’t crash your app". You can ship your app with as many assertions as you want. Swift just won't evaluate your conditions inside assertion block in release app

Comment: I think it would be better to use unit tests to validate the result of the computation instead of asserting at runtime. If the invalid result handled gracefully then you should not use assert. Both assert and precondition are for for terminating execution early when you can not *meaningfully* recover from an invalid state. The main difference is if the code your write is going to be used internally or by others. If you ship the a release of library to be used by an other team then you have to use preconditions.

Answer (score 110):

I found [Swift asserts - the missing manual](http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/03/09/swift-asserts-the-missing-manual/) to be helpful

```
                        debug   release   release
function                -Onone  -O       -Ounchecked
assert()                YES     NO        NO
assertionFailure()      YES     NO        NO**
precondition()          YES     YES       NO
preconditionFailure()   YES     YES       YES**
fatalError()*           YES     YES       YES
```

And from [Interesting discussions on Swift Evolution](http://ericasadun.com/2015/12/15/interesting-discussions-on-swift-evolution/)

> – assert: checking your own code for internal errors
>
> – precondition: for checking that your clients have given you valid arguments.

Also, you need to be careful on what to use, see [assertionFailure and Optimization Level](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/39)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference of own code and client? As for client do you mean like inserting numbers where a String is expected? Shouldn't that be treated with some simple error handling?

Comment: @Honey I think he means about the arguments / results from network API calling, or client's own plugins.

Comment: Client would be someone using your code, say you're writing a library and a programmer passes invalid data. You wouldn't want to gracefully continue since that could be considered a serious programming error.

You should probably never crash on invalid networking API data since that is very unhelpful for the user.

Comment: @onmyway133: From the Xcode QuickHelp, I think `precondition()` and `preconditionFailure()` are *having the same behaviors*. The different between these functions is: `precondition` need a condition inside, while `preconditionFailure` just throw out.

Answer (score 20):

The `precondition` is active in release mode so you when you ship your app and the precondition failed the app will terminate.
`Assert` works just in debug mode as default.

I found this great explanation when to use it on NSHipster:

> Assertions are a concept borrowed from classical logic. In logic,
>   assertions are statements about propositions within a proof. In
>   programming, assertions denote assumptions the programmer has made
>   about the application at the place where they are declared.
>
> When used in the capacity of preconditions and postconditions, which
>   describe expectations about the state of the code at the beginning and
>   end of execution of a method or function, assertions form a contract.
>   Assertions can also be used to enforce conditions at run-time, in
>   order to prevent execution when certain preconditions fail.

Comment: Assertions can be enabled and disabled using a compiler flag; they can be active in shipped code.

Answer (score 6):

> **precondition**

```
func precondition(condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = default, file: StaticString = default, line: UWord = default)
```

Check a necessary condition for making forward progress.

1. Use this function to detect conditions that must prevent the program
   from proceeding even in shipping code.
2. In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode's Debug
   configuration): if condition evaluates to false, stop program
   execution in a debuggable state after printing message.
3. In -O builds (the default for Xcode's Release configuration): if
   condition evaluates to false, stop program execution.
4. In -Ounchecked builds, condition is not evaluated, but the optimizer
   may assume that it would evaluate to true. Failure to satisfy that
   assumption in -Ounchecked builds is a serious programming error.

> **assert**

```
func assert(condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = default, file: StaticString = default, line: UWord = default)
```

Traditional C-style assert with an optional message.

1. Use this function for internal sanity checks that are active during
   testing but do not impact performance of shipping code. To check for
   invalid usage in Release builds; see precondition.
2. In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode's Debug
       configuration): if condition evaluates to false, stop program
       execution in a debuggable state after printing message.
3. In -O builds (the default for Xcode's Release configuration),
       condition is not evaluated, and there are no effects
4. In -Ounchecked builds, condition is not evaluated, but the optimizer
       may assume that it would evaluate to true. Failure to satisfy that
       assumption in -Ounchecked builds is a serious programming erro

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my 2 cents. You can add as many assertions in your code as you want. You can Ship your code with these assertions. Swift does NOT evaluate these code blocks for production apps. These are only evaluated in case of debug mode.

[Adding documentation link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

Also attaching image from swift.org

[image]

Also note, this is not the case with preconditions.
Code shipped with preconditions will crash and app will terminate if preconditions are not evaluated to be true.

So in short, assertions are for debugging, but can be shipped without impacting production. Assertions will be evaluated in debug mode but not in production.

And

PreConditions are for making sure unexpected things do not happen on production environment. Those conditions are evaluated and will terminate your app in case they're evaluated to be false

Answer (score 0):

**iOS assert vs precondition vs fatal**

General rule:

```
1. -O(-O, -Osize) - compile out(do not execute) `assert` and `assertionFailure`
2. -Ounchecked(as `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = -Ounchecked` or `SWIFT_DISABLE_SAFETY_CHECKS` = true) 
 2.1 set `condition: true` into `assert(condition: true)` and `precondition(condition: true)` that is why app is not terminated
 2.2 optimizer is free to assume that `assertionFailure` and `preconditionFailure` code are never called
```

Error looks like

```
Experiments2/ViewController.swift:20: Assertion failed: Some error
2022-12-11 15:17:28.772447+0200 Experiments2[95061:10414104] Experiments2/ViewController.swift:20: Assertion failed: Some error
```

1. `assert(condition: Bool, message: String)`
2. `assertionFailure(message: String)`
3. `precondition(condition: Bool, message: String)`
4. `preconditionFailure(message: String) -> Never`
5. `fatalError(message: String) -> Never`

`Never` create build time warning

```
Will never be executed
```

[image]

[[Optimization Level(SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL)]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74835704/4770877)

- `-Onone` - by default for **app debug**
- `-O` - by default for **app release**

```
|                                   | -Onone    |                    -O                     |                 -O -Ounchecked                    |                   -Ounchecked                     |
|--------------------------------   |:------:   |:----------------------------------------: |:----------------------------------------------:   |:----------------------------------------------:   |
| assert(condition: false)          |  TRUE     |       FALSE -O (compile out assert)       |          FALSE -O (compile out assert)            |      FALSE -Ounchecked (condition == true)        |
| assertionFailure                  |  TRUE     | FALSE -O (compiled out assertionFailure)  |    FALSE  -O (compile out assertionFailure)       | TRUE or FALSE -Ounchecked(may never be called)    |
| precondition(condition: false)    |  TRUE     |                   TRUE                    |      FALSE -Ounchecked (condition == true)        |      FALSE -Ounchecked (condition == true)        |
| preconditionFailure               |  TRUE     |                   TRUE                    | TRUE or FALSE -Ounchecked(may never be called)    | TRUE or FALSE -Ounchecked(may never be called)    |
| fatalError                        |  TRUE     |                   TRUE                    |                      TRUE                         |                      TRUE                         |
```

```
TRUE - app is terminated
FALSE - app is not terminated
```