# Add assert while unwrapping optional in swift

Tags: swift, assert, preconditions

I have an optional value, and I want to add an *assert* if the value is `nil`.
So, I want to do something like:

```
if let val = val {
    ...
} else {
    assertionFailure("No fields for key \(my dictionary key)")
}
```

My question is, will the `assertionFailure`above result in a crash in my production app?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539616-assertionfailure ?

Comment: @luk2302 i had but understand nothing.

Comment: What is unclear about *"Use this function to stop the program, **without impacting the performance of shipping code,**  ..."*  and *"In -O builds, has **no effect.**"* ?

Comment: And To protect code from invalid usage in Release builds, see preconditionFailure

Comment: @MartinR what is -O build?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34379407/1187415. – "-O" is "with optimization", and that is how the archives for app store release are built.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between “precondition” and “assert” in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673027/difference-between-precondition-and-assert-in-swift).

Comment: @MartinR ok, thanks you.

Comment: What will you do differently in your production app when the optional binding fails?