# Displaying text before user.displayName - Swift 3

Tags: swift

I want to display "created by" before displaying username.

Can anyone help ????

Code:

```
if let user = DataService.dataService.currentUser {
  username.text = user.displayName
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate strings in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034174/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-swift)

Comment: You should read [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11) book before posting any more questions about Swift.

Comment: nope,never, not gonna happen

Comment: Really? Apple provides a free book on their Swift language and you have no interest in actually learning the language?

Answer (score 1):

```
if let user = DataService.dataService.currentUser {
username.text = "created by \(user.displayName)"
}
```