# Parameters: [String: Any]

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string: Any array, like this

```
public var parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "myParameters": "all",
    //"fromDate": Date = Date()
    //"searchByName": String = ""
]
```

I would like to add value `"sampleValue"` to the default value `"all"`, so the array looks like this.

```
[
  "parameterSetOne": "all, sampleValue",
  "parameterSetTwo" : 20.00,
   "parameterSetThree" : date(),
]
```

Comment: I had the results of "myParameters": ["all", "sampleValue"], this results needs to be part of a API payload. with bracket it is not accepted by the API call. Only this format is accepted . "myParameters": "all", "sampleValue"

Comment: That's not a valid kind, valid JSON or else. It means that you have to build it yourself, but it's strange that your API have a strange format.

Comment: @Larme, can you please elaborate on that? I will bring it to the backend developer and ask for an explanation. Thanks for look into this.

Comment: Your back-end developer expects JSON or not? if yes, copy/paste `["myParameters": "all", "sampleValue"]` into a JSON validator (plenty online tools) you'll see. And if you back-end developer really expects JSON, he/she needs to give your a real example. What you gave is strange, and in coding, each char is important, so please be careful. I answered on the other question what could be done, but that's GUESSING that's the deisred output.

Comment: @Larme, I think you got the answer, the backend developer is expecting "parameterSetOne": "all, sampleValue"

Comment: @Larme, thank you for your time and your help! If you put your response as the answer, I will mark it as answer.

Comment: ` the backend developer is expecting "parameterSetOne": "all, sampleValue"` finally! Be careful next time, you'll loose time (both yours and ours) with misleading informations ;)

Comment: @Larme, totally agree, only if they give me an example what to expected from the front instead of let me doing the guessing game.

Comment: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034174/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-in-swift) about concatenating strings

Answer (score 1):

```
parameters["parameterSetOne"] = parameters["parameterSetOne"] as! String + " sampleValue"
```

But you have to make sure that it is really a String value in "parameterSetOne"