# Cannot assign property in method of struct

Tags: swift

In Swift, I'm trying to do the following:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar = 1

    func baz() {
        bar = 2
    }
}
```

Xcode reports the error `Cannot assign to 'bar' in self` on the line in the method.

Why? If I change the struct to a class, there's no error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift and mutating struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035648/swift-and-mutating-struct)

Comment: You're right, that's a better question and answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to modify the properties of the struct, mark the function as mutating.

```
struct Foo {
    var bar = 1

    mutating func baz() {
        bar = 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you cannot assign to a struct's variable from within the struct itself is because instance methods of a struct cannot mutate instance variables. For this to work you need to add the keyword mutating before the declaration of the function.

This will give you the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar = 1

    mutating func baz() {
        bar = 2
    }
}
```

The function baz() will now be able to mutate the instance variables of the struct.