# Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable, I know how to fix but needs understanding

Tags: swift

I have a `struct` :

```
public struct MyStruct {
  public var myInt: Int = 0
  ...
}
```

I have a extension of `MyStruct`:

```
extension MyStruct {

  public func updateValue(newValue: Int) {
     // ERROR: Cannot assigned to property: 'self' is immutable
     self.MyInt = newValue
  }
}
```

I got the error showing above, I know I can fix the error by several ways, e.g. add a `mutating` keyword before `func`.

I am here not asking how to fix the error, but ask why swift doesn't allow this kind of value assignment ? I need an explanation besides a fix.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035648/swift-and-mutating-struct.

Comment: Or directly from the Swift documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html: *"Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods.

However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method."*

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**struct** is  a **value type**. For value types, only methods explicitly marked as mutating can **modify** the properties of self, so this is not possible within a **computed** property.

If you change  **struct** to be a **class** then your code compiles without problems.

Structs are value types which means they are copied when they are passed around.So if you change a copy you are changing only that copy, not the original and not any other copies which might be around.If your struct is immutable then all automatic copies resulting from being passed by value will be the same.If you want to change it you have to consciously do it by creating a new instance of the struct with the modified data. (not a copy)

Comment: Although structs are pass by value there's copy on write which means that for structs that are not mutated they are essentially copying around the same memory just like a reference type. Otherwise this would cause a huge performance problem. All the OP has to do is mark his function `mutating`.

Answer (score 32):

A tricky one: mark it as @State. Structs are immutable objects so normal properties cannot be modified after their initializer. Adding this kind of label you are converting it into mutating properties.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Sure! Structs are immutable objects so normal properties cannot be modified after their initializer. Adding this kind of label you are converting it into mutating properties.

Answer (score -2):

Because a Struct is a value type, and therefore should be immutable

Comment: Why value type should be immutable?

Comment: Value types are mutable, you just have to declare them as mutable.

Comment: So by default they are immutable, right? Default, value type immutable. Value type immutable.

Comment: structs are not immutable. we have `vars` and `mutating` funcs. Not a problem. The OP needs to mark his function `mutating`. When you mutate a struct though notice it makes a copy of itself. So if you attach a property observer it will call `didSet`. classes will not make copies of themselves when mutated. So, if you have a property to one and mutate the instance the `didSet` observer is not called.