# How to return value from a closure in a Struct in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I'm retrieving data from a website.

Networking works well. Data is parsed correctly from JSON.

A couple of references - In this struct:

- Replies is the datamodel for the JSON
- PrepareQuestions is a func which performs the parsing (I have it in an extension of the same Struct)

I'd like to have an object within this struct (downloadedData - 'Replies' is the struct with the datamodel) containing all the information downloaded, but I incur into an error due to "self being an immutable capture". Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
    struct QuestionsManager {
    
    var downloadedData:Replies?
    
    func useData() {
        manageQuestions(url: K.urlForRetreival, numberOfQuestions: K.numberOfSquares) { [self] (replies, error) in
            if let replies = replies {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    downloadedData = replies // Here I got the error
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func manageQuestions(url: String, numberOfQuestions: String, myCompletion: @escaping (Replies?, Error?)->()) {
        let generatedUrl = URL(string: url + numberOfQuestions)!
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: generatedUrl) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let fetchedData = data {
                    let fetchedProcessedData = prepareQuestions(data: fetchedData)
                    myCompletion(fetchedProcessedData, nil)
                    return
                }
            } else {
                myCompletion(nil, error)
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this error because the closure captures an immutable `self`.

Just like primitive types (e.g. `Int`), `struct`s are value-types, and Swift is built with the notion of immutability of value-types.

In other words, if you had `let questionManager = QuestionManager()`, you'd expect  `questionManager` not to change. Even if it was a `var`, it can only mutate via direct action by the caller, e.g. `questionManager.doMutatingFunc()`.

But, if a closure was allowed to capture self, it could modify itself at some later point. This is not allowed.

This simplest (only?) way to fix this is to turn `QuestionManager` into a `class`:

```
class QuestionManager {
   // ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks - It actually worked and I should have thought about it! The resulting "downloadedData" shows up as nil though (while I'm sure the parsing works well) - Do you think it depends from the networking time? Should I solve the problem with a completion handler?

Answer (score 0):

> struct is a value type. For value types, only methods explicitly
> marked as mutating can modify the properties of self, so this is not
> possible within a computed property.
>
> If you change struct to be a class then your code compiles without
> problems.
>
> Structs are value types which means they are copied when they are
> passed around.So if you change a copy you are changing only that copy,
> not the original and not any other copies which might be around.If
> your struct is immutable then all automatic copies resulting from
> being passed by value will be the same.If you want to change it you
> have to consciously do it by creating a new instance of the struct
> with the modified data.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/49253452/11734662