# cannot able to make struct variable as mutable type

Tags: ios, struct, expression, immutability, swift5

I am facing the issue of "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool'" . Please look at the below code. I am getting error in `viewForHeaderInSection`. Actually where should i do modification to make it work?.

```
struct VenueDetail {
        var isVeg: Bool
}

struct VenueDetailDTOMapper {

    static func map(_ dto: DetailDataDTO) -> VenueDetail {
     return VenueDetail(isVeg: dto.isVeg)
    }
}
```

In API Manager I have get the data from api and use above struct as follow

```
let venueDetail = VenueDetailDTOMapper.map(getDetail)
```

ViewModel:

```
enum VenueDetailVMTypes {
    case veueInfoInfo
}

protocol VenueDetailVMItems {
 var type: VenueDetailVMTypes { get }
}

struct VenueInfoViewModel: VenueDetailVMItems {
        var type: VenueDetailVMTypes {
            return .veueInfoInfo
            }
        var headerSection: VenueDetail
}

func cretaDataSource() {

    if let getVenueDetails = self.venueDetails {
        let vmType = VenueInfoViewModel(headerSection: getVenueDetails)
        arrayDataSource.append(vmType)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

       let headerView = UIView()

       let venueDetailVMItems = viewModel.arrayDataSource[section]
       switch venueDetailVMItems.type {
       case .veueInfoInfo:
           let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kCellIdentifierVenueHeader) as! VenueHeaderTVCell
           headerCell.updateCellData(detail: (venueDetailVMItems as! VenueInfoViewModel).headerSection)

           headerCell.foodTypeHandler = { [weak self] (isOn) in
               guard let strongSelf = self else {
                   return
               }                
            strongSelf.viewModel.showOnlyVegMenu(shouldShowVeg: isOn)
            (venueDetailVMItems as! VenueInfoViewModel).headerSection.isVeg = isOn.  //Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool'
            strongSelf.tableView.reloadData()
           }
           headerView.addSubview(headerCell)
           break
       }
       return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A structure is an aggregation of fields; if a particular structure instance is mutable, its fields will be mutable; if an instance is immutable, its fields will be immutable. A structure type must thus be prepared for the possibility that the fields of any particular instance may be mutable or immutable.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24222226/2991942)

So try to change ***let*** to be **var**

Make sure the the `arrayDataSource` is mutable user **var** not ***let***

```
var arrayDataSource = [VenueInfoViewModel]()
```

Comment: i appreciated but still its giving issue. Actually all i want to change  viewModel.arrayDataSource[section].headerSection.isVeg = true

Answer (score 1):

Structs are value types, so each time you assign a struct, it makes a copy. You're treating it as a reference type. Stripping away all the `as!` casting, what you've done is:

```
let value = array[index]
value.someBool = true
reloadData()
```

Even if value were mutable (which it could be), that wouldn't do anything. `value` is a *copy* of `array[index]`, not a reference to it. If you want it to be a reference, then you need to make it a reference type (a class).

You've used a protocol and a "type" identifier, where what I think you really wanted was an enum with associated data:

```
enum VenueDetail {
    case veueInfoInfo(VenueInfoViewModel)
}
```

With this, you get rid of all of the dangerous and complicated `as!` casting.

But all of that doesn't really change the issue you're describing. Either way (with a protocol or with an enum), what you need to do is:

```
var value = array[index]
// change value the ways you want; set the bool, etc.
array[index] = value
```

Comment: Yes, i am aware of assigning a struct to other is just creating other copy. Alright i think its better to convert struct to class. The reason being i defined a enum cause i have pasted only one case, there are multiple sections of different types i need, so casting will be there. Actually all i want to change viewModel.arrayDataSource[section].headerSection.isVeg = true

Comment: Enums can have their own data (associated data), so you don't need to cast. That's the point of my `veueInfoInfo` case; it includes an associated VenueInfoViewModel. You can also have another case that has a completely different type of associated data. With that, you just `switch` on the type. There's no need to `as!`.

Answer (score -1):

After struggling i just create a method in `viewModel` that removes objects in array of type `.venueInfo` and reload, i know its kind of hack but time being i have no option. In case if somebody found better way, really appreciated

```
 func changeHeaderSwitch(isVeg: Bool) {

    arrayDataSource.removeAll { (venueDetailVMItems) -> Bool in
        return venueDetailVMItems.type == .veueInfoInfo
    }

    if var getVenueDetails = self.venueDetails {
        getVenueDetails.isVeg = isVeg
        let vmType = VenueInfoViewModel(headerSection: getVenueDetails, arrayMenuInfo: [])
        arrayDataSource.append(vmType)
    }
}
```