# SwiftUI: What is the difference between var and let as a parameter in List's Row?

Tags: swift, swiftui

What is the difference between **var and let** as a parameter in **List's Row**?

Usually, if I don't change the landmark variable, the compiler will warn me, but there is no warning in that row. I wonder why.

```
struct LandmarkRow: View {
    var landmark: Landmark

    var body: some View {
        Text(landmark.id)
    }
}
```

```
struct LandmarkRow: View {
    let landmark: Landmark

    var body: some View {
        Text(landmark.id)
    }
}
```

This looks like a same result:

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(landmarks, id: \.id) { landmark in
            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In a SwiftUI `View` there is no difference except for semantics.

A `struct` is immutable therefore having a `var` vs a `let` is irrelevant.

`let` Is semantically correct

Comment: Wht do you really mean by `A struct is immutable`?

Comment: You can't change the pieces of a `struct` by default you can only change it as a whole. That is why SwiftUI has wrappers. https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/use-swift-struct-for-total-immutability-6f07388cad5e

Comment: The wrappers control the changes of the pieces/parts of the SwiftUI `View`.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: @mahan A struct is not immutable per se - only if the struct value is itself constant. So, having a `let v = MyStruct()` which has `var name: String` does _not_ let you modify the name property of `v`. But a `var v = MyStruct()` is itself mutable, and thus its var properties can be mutated. In SwiftUI, you usually deal with constant Views, so having a `var somePorperty` is unusual.

Comment: You can't change a `var` inside a SwiftUI `View` you need a SwiftUI wrapper to change it. The OP is talking in the context of a SwiftUI `View`

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Agree!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler warns you about **local** variables which are never been modified or being unused.

But you get never a warning about declared struct members / class properties. And a SwiftUI view is actually a regular struct.

However you get an **error** if you are going to modify a struct member / class property which is declared as constant.

Answer (score 1):

**var** is a variable meaning it is mutable. You can reassign it a value as many time as you wish.

In `LandmarkRow` and `LandmarkList`, `var body` is a **computed property** that calculates (rather than stores) a value. And it's **read-only**.  Computed properties can **only** be declared using `var`.

> When you implement a custom view, you must implement a computed
> `body` property to provide the content for your view. Return a view
> that's composed of primitive views that SwiftUI provides, plus other  composite views that you've already defined. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/body-swift.property

`let` is used to declare a constant. You can assign it a value exactly once as you have done in  `LandmarkList`. In other words, you can not reassign it a value.

```
List(landmarks, id: \.id) { landmark in
     LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
}
```

#### Example

```
struct Example {
    // variable that you can change
    var name: String

    // constant that can only be assigned a value once.
    let fileExtension: String
    
    // A computed property that is read-only
    var filename: String {
        return name + "." + fileExtension
    }
}
```

```
var example = Example(name: "example", fileExtension: "swift")
```

You can change name from `example` to `example_2` since it is a `variable`.

```
example.name = "example_2"
```

You can not change `fileExtension` from `swift` to `js` because `fileExtension` is a constant (let). If you do so, you will get the following error.

> Cannot assign to property: 'fileExtension' is a 'let' constant

```
example.fileExtension = "js"
```

You can not change `fileName` because it is a **read-only** property. If you try to change, you will get this error.

> Cannot assign to property: 'filename' is a get-only property

```
example.filename = "ex.js"
```

#### More info

[What is the difference between `let` and `var` in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/computed-property/

Comment: You will get an error trying to change `var name: String` that only works in a `class` from inside the `struct` such as in a SwiftUI `View` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035648/swift-and-mutating-struct

Comment: The question was targeted towards the context of parameters declared in `View`

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to SwiftUI. I only have backgound in C and C++. I am guessing that it has to do with the fact that you declared landmark but didn't initialized it (or in this case, default value). Here, it assumes that you will initialize landmark when you initialize a LandmarkRow. Getting back to the point, I think the compiler doesn't know if landmark changes or not untill it is run.

Comment: `landmark` is initialized, see [Swift memberwise initializers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID214).

Comment: If you read carefully, I meant it is initialized only when the struct LandmarkRow is initialized. I was more focused on differentiating let and var insider a Struct. My answer is quite similar to vadian's above. The compiler just won't know if it's modified before actually running the program.

Answer (score 0):

var => Variable

By defining var you inform the compiler that this variable will be changed in further execution of code.

var current_day = 6

let => Constant

By defining let you inform the compiler that this is a constant variable and its value stays the same.
Like
let earth_gravity = 9.8

***Its just best practise to make unchanging variables constant.
There will be no difference in execution of output.***