# Why is "let" used instead of var in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

On this page http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift, many of the examples use *let* instead of *var*.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
  cellForRowAtIndexPath
  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell =
      tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
      as UITableViewCell

  let person = people[indexPath.row]
  cell.textLabel!.text = person.valueForKey("name") as String?

  return cell
}
```

I see this in lots of tutorials. Is there some reason to use *let* in the above snippet over *var*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a matter of fact, as a Swift programmer, the question to ask is why *not* use `var` over `let`? This is one area where Swift differs greatly in semantics from other languages such as C#.

The reason is because once you obtain a reference to a table cell, that reference is not going to change for the lifetime of each invocation of this method. There are no reassignments to `cell`, because there is simply no reason to do so. And therefore there is no reason to make `cell` a variable.

In general, in Swift, you should [default to using `let`, and only use `var` if you need to reassign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374151/swift-when-should-i-use-var-instead-of-let/28374271#28374271). Remember that `let` only prevents the constant itself from being *reassigned*; you can still mutate the object that is being referenced, as is being done in `cell.textLabel!.text = person...` in this case.

There are other, subtle differences that are further covered in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html), but this applies to the majority of cases.

Comment: Are there any compiler improvements to using `let` over `var`? Is `var` slower or anything? Is it just indicating semantics?

Comment: @Bjorn Tipling: The compiler will not let you reassign to a constant declared using `let`, and will error out if it notices you trying to do so, either by mistake or on purpose.

Comment: I'm comparing to c# where the above would both be variables. It seems strange to declare everything as constants.  But I agree if the storage is never going to change, `let` works.

Comment: @BoltClock: what is the bang syntax after textLabel?

Comment: @4thSpace: That's known as forced unwrapping, where `cell.textLabel` is an optional and you're unwrapping its value when you know it always has a value at that specific point in time (so you don't have to do a nil check every time). In this case, it means you know that the cell *always* has a text label so you can just get the reference to the label immediately.

Comment: @4thSpace I believe you are talking about `!` symbol in the code. It is called optional forced unwrapping. You can read about them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034483/what-is-an-unwrapped-value-in-swift)

Comment: Ah - yes.  I know it now. For those variables that can be null or nil.  Thanks.

Comment: Except for the compiler check are there any advantages for using `let` over `var`? Speed? Memory use? Like I'm not going to get mad at myself for using var over let in code only I will ever see.