# Cannot invoke '+=' with an argument list of (Double, @lvalue Double)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm running into a weird error by Xcode:

> Cannot invoke '+=' with an argument list of (Double, @lvalue Double)

Given the following code using iOS SDK 8.1 and Xcode 6.1.1. (You can simply put this into a Playground and test it.)

```
class Mark {
    var description: String
    var mark: Double
    var weight: Double

    init(description: String, mark: Double, weight: Double) {
        self.description = description
        self.mark = mark
        self.weight = weight
    }
}

// in some other class
var marks = [Mark(description: "", mark: 5, weight: 1), Mark(description: "", mark: 4, weight: 0.5)] // sample data

var totalMarks: Double {
    let total = 0.0
    for mark in marks {
        total += mark.mark // Cannot invoke '+=' with an argument list of (Double, @lvalue Double)
    }
    return total
}
```

Xcode says `total` is a `Double`, `mark` is a `Mark` and I assume `mark.mark` must be a `Double` as defined.

Am I missing to import a module? I only import `Foundation` at the moment, which I guess should be enough.

Comment: Sure that `let` is appropriate? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift

Comment: Oh dammed. I love and hate `let` at the same time.

Comment: 'twis why there is `var` for a [Ménage à trois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_%C3%A0_trois)