# What is the different between `if var` and `if let` in swift?

Tags: swift

Consider this two codes:

```
if let myValue = myObject.value as NSString?{
 //logic here
}
```

vs

```
if var myValue = myObject.value as NSString?{
 //logic here
}
```

I know the let keyword is define a constant, is this mean that the first line of code, if the `myObject.value` is NSString , the `myValue` constant will be made? This looks confusing.

Comment: I would argue this is not a duplicate of [What is the difference between `let` and `var` in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the post "What is the difference between `let` and `var`?" The `if let` and `if var` optional binding are different

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use the `let` then you will not be able to change `myValue`.

```
if let myValue = myObject.value as NSString? {
    myValue = "Something else" // <-- Compiler error
}
```

On the other hand with `var` you can.

```
if var myValue = myObject.value as NSString? {
    myValue = "Something else" // <-- It's fine
}
```

Please note that `myValue` does exists only within the scope of the `if` and changing its value does not produce effect outside of its scope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your (almost) last sentence is wrong.
Check http://swiftstub.com/774222102/

Comment: In your example you are not changing the value of `test`. You are changing a value `referenced` by `test`. It's different. I think my sentence is correct: if you change the value of `myValue` you do not produce effects outside of its scope.

Comment: Anyway you made a smart observation. I am going to update my answer in order to include your example.

Comment: Some types are `reference types` and those will always refer to another value. Other's are `value types` and for those you are right.

Comment: Yes in Swift we have `Reference Type` when we use a `Class` and `Value Type` when we use a `Struct`, an `Enum` or a `Tuple`.

But please note that this does not change my answer. `myValue` can be a Class, a Struct, an Enum or a Typle. If I change its value inside the `IF` (I mean I write `myValue = something`) the effect does not propagate outside the IF.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `if let myValue = ...`  will not allow you to change the referenced object through `myValue`. That is, inside the block, `myValue.someProperty = aValue` will generate a compiler error, just as trying to assign to `myValue` itself.

Answer (score 7):

You use `let` to create a constant, so in the first example you cannot change `myValue`.

When you use `var`, `myValue` is a variable which you can change inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The variable type is a different depending if you are using let or var.

let is final and can not be changed afterwards.
var is a normal variable.

Your myValue cannot be changed or modified if you using let in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

The example you stated is of Optional Binding

Optional binding is used to determine whether an optional has a value, and if so, to make that value available as a temporary **constant** or **variable**.

```
if let myValue = myObject.value as NSString?{
 //logic here
}
```

Above code will extract `myObject.value` if exist as a **constant**, whereas the code below will extract `myObject.value` as a **variable**

```
if var myValue = myObject.value as NSString?{
 //logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

“Use **let** to make a constant and **var** to make a variable.
The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign it a value exactly once.

This means you can use constants to name a value that you determine once but use in many places.

```
 var myVariable = 42
 myVariable = 50
 let myConstant = 42
```

A constant or variable must have the same type as the value you want to assign to it.

However, you don’t always have to write the type explicitly. Providing a value when you create a constant or variable lets the compiler infer its type.

In the example above, the compiler infers that myVariable is an integer because its initial value is an integer.

Read the : [iBook](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=881256329) The Swift Programming Language

Thanks .