# Why and when to use let keyword to declare empty dictionary or an empty array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I searched on SO but did not find any related question.

I was referring to online swift programming language resource and I found following piece of code:

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()
```

My question is why use let keyword and when?

I need an explanation so I can understand the fundamentals correctly.

Edit:

What will happen internally for the above line and when I should use them?

Comment: Read the Swift ebook from Apple.

Comment: Apple doc: [Swift basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

Comment: why people down voted this question. I am new to this language completely.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to always use `let` (immutable) unless it's absolutely necessary for you to use `var` (mutable).

Comment: People is voting down because it seems you didn't try hard enough to find the answer for your question before ask, as the use of "let" is clearly documented in the apple documentation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift.

Comment: For them who down voted this question: @Dheeraj gave answer which I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[From apple documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> Constants and variables associate a name (such as
>   maximumNumberOfLoginAttempts or welcomeMessage) with a value of a
>   particular type (such as the number 10 or the string "Hello"). The
>   value of a constant cannot be changed once it is set, whereas a
>   variable can be set to a different value in the future.

```
let maximumNumberOfLoginAttempts = 10
var currentLoginAttempt = 0
```

The following code:

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()
```

as the variable names suggest will create an emptyArray and an emptyDictionary that cannot be changed and will be forever empty.

Comment: Why do people downvote this? Seems like a completely legit answer to me.

Comment: @LubošTurek I didn't get it too, I just hope it helped Simple Man anyway!

Comment: I am asking those folks who down vote this question. Anyway I got my answer.

Comment: @SimpleMan Glad to hear man, good luck in your new journey with swift!

Comment: Thank you. But please explain above comment "array with 10 elements "?

Comment: @SimpleMan I was just trying to say once you create an array with "let" any of the values inside the array can be changed

Comment: Yes you are right. I can alter the value but I won't be able to add new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let` keyword when your array or disctionary will not get modified anywhere in the code that means it is constant. When you declared array or dictionary as

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()
```

then emptyArray is initialized with 0 `String` values in it means it is initialized but empty. Similarly emptyDictionary is initialized with 0 items of type `[String: Float]` in it.