# Variable Is Not Incrementing

Tags: swift

I have to make some calculus based on two dates and the user says if it should calc the initial month or not.

My code is like this:

```
 let qtMeses = getMonthDifference( dateaq!, d2: datebase! )
    if ( proprioMesSwitch.on  ){
      let qtMeses = qtMeses + 1
    }
```

The routine count how many month between the two dates and check to see if the user checked the initial month option.

Say the qtMeses variable has a value of 20 after calling the getMonthDifference procedure. After it tests the proprioMesSwitch and executes the let qtMeses = qtMeses + 1 line but even though the result after that is still the same 20.

Answer (score 2):

With let ... you define a new variable qtMeses, hiding the outer one.

Use:

```
var qtMeses = getMonthDifference( dateaq!, d2: datebase! )
if (proprioMesSwitch.on) {
   qtMeses = qtMeses + 1
}
```

Comment: And then if he increments, he should use var instead of let, because let defines a constant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift

Comment: @SwiftRabbit Oops! You are correct. I will update the snippet.

Comment: I saw your answer when I posted mine. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have declared a variable qtMeses with var qtMeses I used let qtMeses to assign a value to this variable.

But because of let qtMeses swift changed my var into a constant that`s why I couldn`t change its value anymore.

```
qtMeses = getMonthDifference( dateaq!, d2: datebase! )
if ( proprioMesSwitch.on  ){
  qtMeses = qtMeses + 1
}
```