# How to change a variable stored property in a structure in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

On apple website, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html
 it states that we can change a variable property in a structure. I am trying to change the person's last name. However I recieve an error at that line of code. Thank you for helping me.

```
import UIKit


struct people {
    let firstName : String
    var lastName : String
}

let person = people(firstName: "InitialFirstName", lastName: "InitialLastName")
person.lastName = "ChangedLastName" //<-- error

println(person.firstName)
println(person.lastName)
```

Error:

> Playground execution failed: TestPlayground2.playground:12:17: error: cannot assign to 'lastName' in 'person'
>   person.lastName = "ChangedLastName"
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only modify a property of a struct if that struct is declared as `var`, and not `let`. Even though your property is `var`, because the struct is `let` it is immutable.

```
var person = people(firstName: "InitialFirstName", lastName: "InitialLastName")
person.lastName = "ChangedLastName" //No problem!
```

Note that this is different behavior from classes. A class's mutable properties can be changed even if if the instance of the class is a constant.

Comment: I forgot that my person was a "let". Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Unlike `class` which is reference type `struct` is value type.
You have to declare the instance as mutable

```
var person = people(firstName: "InitialFirstName", lastName: "InitialLastName")
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the 'let' syntax you have declared 'person' as a constant, which means that it's properties can't be changed. Just change 'let' to 'var' and the error will disappear.

Here's more info about the [difference between `let` and `var` in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift).