# Mutable Array in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I use a Mutable Strongly Type array in Swift? I am adding ShoppingList object to an Array like this:

```
 func getAllShoppingLists() -> Array<ShoppingList> {

        let shoppingLists = Array<ShoppingList>()

        db.open()

        let results = try! db.executeQuery("SELECT * from ShoppingLists", values: nil)

        defer {

            db.close()
        }

        while(results.next()) {

            let shoppingList = ShoppingList()
            shoppingList.title = results.stringForColumn("title")

            shoppingLists.append(shoppingList)
        }

        return shoppingLists
    }
```

The problem comes that the shoppingLists is declared as "let". If I change to "var" it works fine. The reason of course is that I am changing the number of items in the array. Is this the best way?

Answer (score 2):

You can create this code,

```
var shoppingArray = [ShoppingList]()
shoppingArray.append(yourInstance)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the only way to make an array mutable, to understand the difference between let and var, see this post, as the answer explains it in detail.

[What is the difference between `let` and `var` in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

Answer (score -1):

That's because `let` represents a constant.

You have to use `var` if you want to be able to change the shoppingLists content.

Comment: You're just repeating what the other answers already say.