# Swift optional initialisation

Tags: swift, initialization, init, option-type, optional-variables

It's my understanding that

```
var perhapsInt : Int?
```

This is automatically set to a `.None` value. And the below code snippet confirms that (no compiler errors)

```
class MyClass {
    var num1: Int = 0
    var num2: Int?

    init(num1: Int) {
        self.num1 = num1
    }
}

var newClass = MyClass(num1: 5)
newClass.num1 // prints '5'
newClass.num2 // prints 'nil'
```

Is my understanding of the optional initialisation process correct? if so why does this not work when I change `num2` to `let`.

I was expecting the same behaviour of optionals defaulting to `nil` when using `let`. Am I missing something here?

```
class MyClass {
    var num1: Int = 0
    let num2: Int?

    init(num1: Int) {
        self.num1 = num1
        // compiler error : return from initialiser without initialising all stored properties 
    }
}    
...
```

My question is, how can both of these cases be true. Shouldn't it be one or the other. Either optional values are automatically set to `.None` or it's not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior of `var num2: Int?` is caused by `Optional`s being sugar-powered. They're the only type in Swift which has an **implicit** default value (of `.None`).

Notice that if you type `var num2: Int` (without `?`) – the compiler will throw the same error, regardless of using `var` vs. `let`.

```
class MyClass {
    var num2: Int
    init() {
        // Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
    }
}
```

Because `let`s' values cannot be overwritten (as opposed to `var`s'), they require you to **explicitly** set their initial value:

```
class MyClass {
    let num2: Int? = nil
}

// or this way

class MyClass {
    let num2: Int?
    init() {
        num2 = nil
    }
}
```

This will, however, result in an useless `nil` constant.

---

You can read more about initialization of stored properties [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254).

Comment: Okay that make sense. Thanks. As a follow up question, why does it work when I initialiser a 'let' inside 'init' but not initialise when I define it? see this block of code. 

class MyClass {
    let num2: Int?
    init() {
        self.num2 = nil
    }
}

shouldn't this throw an error around 'let num2: Int?' line

Comment: No. `let` only requires you to **assign the value once, no more, no less**. When talking about initializers, they require all `let`s to have a value before initialization finishes. Therefore you may do this either via default value, _or_ in the initializer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a lot of discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift).
A statement from that thread - look deeper in the link above

> The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but
>   you must assign it a value exactly once.

Intresting that you code will compile if you set let value like:

```
let num2: Int? = .None
let num2: Int? = nil
```

Comment: Yeah that make sense as there are two ways to initialise a variable (or constant) in swift. 1. default values (which you have done here) or 2. initialise using a init method