# Why let at function scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope

I understand the block vs. function scoping of `let` & `var` (or I thought I did). Recently I ran across some JavaScript that used `let` in function scope where I thought it would be equivalent to using `var`, like:

```
function xyz ( abc ) {
    let mno = abc - 1;   /* or whatever */
    ...
}
```

Is there any functional difference between that and using `var` there?  Or is it just a stylistic thing?

Comment: The answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword

Comment: Some people believe `var` should never have been in the language, and would use `let` in all cases, as promoting good practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference whatsoever. It's either a stylistic thing or a misunderstanding of how `var` and `let` work. Perhaps the original author (the person who wrote the function you saw) thought that `let` is the same as `const` (which is *almost* the case in [languages like Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)). In other words, sometimes people bring styles/syntax from one language into another because the declarations look similar, but in reality mean completely different things.

> I understand the block vs. function scoping of let & var (or I thought I did)

Don't worry, you do. `let` is for block-scoping, just as you pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, I was burned by perl's ridiculous `my` scoping once, so I wanted to make sure there wasn't some silly corner case I was unaware of.

Comment: No problem. No weird corner cases here, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Except that `var` hoists while `let` works well - in a less silly and confusing manner. Many have advocated that you should replace `var` everywhere because its just less confusing for programmers from other languages.

Answer (score 4):

One difference inside function scope would be that [temporal dead zone](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified/) can occur if you try to reference a `let` before it's defined:

```
function example() {
    console.log(a); // undefined
    console.log(b); // ReferenceError: b is not defined
    var a = 1;
    let b = 2;
}
```

Comment: @max Not sure, but I remember reading a while back that he was basically rushed by Netscape to come back to them in 10 days with a new language prototype (hence all the strange js bugs that carry through to today)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/5767783), there is no difference in the case you described, they're functionally the same as they're both in the scope of the function. As you guessed, probably just the person (or linter) wanting to be consistent in defining variables.