# Swift Hoisting?

Tags: swift, hoisting

As everyone knows, JavaScript "Hoists" the variables to the top of the file or scope. But from my understanding, using `let` is the same as `var` only `let` is confined to the scope it is defined in.

Being a compiled language instead of an interpreted, can we assume Swift does NOT do this?

For example:

```
x = 10

var y = x + 10

var x
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing to me, but assuming there is not another declaration of `x` anywhere else, this won't compile in Swift. http://i.imgur.com/rrjHvS8.png

Comment: I've found this useful: [What is the difference between `let` and `var` in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

Comment: @MartinR I think OP is referring to the behaviour of JavaScript and asking if the behaviour is the same in Swift - one key difference is that `var` (in JS) hoists variables to the nearest function scope; `let` does not, and is block scoped instead. In this sense, the main difference between the two is the scope they are accessible in. Still, the question is founded on an incorrect assumption: This behaviour isn't because JavaScript is compiled or interpreted, it's because `var` had a weird specification.

Comment: @DanPantry: You are right, I did not read the question correctly. I apologize for that and I'll remove my comment and the closing vote. – However, I still don't consider it a good question because OP could have checked quickly that it does not work like that in Swift.

Comment: @MartinR Not looking to debate whether or not it's a good question - just hoping to clear up any ambiguities :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can we assume Swift does NOT do this?

You can assume whatever you want, but no matter the programming language, your absolute best bet it to just try it and find out.  If you would have pasted your sample code into a Playground or in any Swift-capable IDE, or just tried running it through the command line, you'd quickly find out that this simply does not work.

---

Your question is somewhat confusing, but I think I can address all or at least most of your questions.

```
x = 10    
var y = x + 10
var x
```

Assuming there is no other code to go with your original sample, it simply does not compile.  All three lines have a problem.

The first two lines complain about the use of an unresolved identified 'x'. In English, this means Swift can't figure out what variable you're talking about.  Variables in Swift must be declared before they are used, so the declaration on line three doesn't help the next two lines.

The third line complains that it can't figure out what type `x` should be.  "Type annotation missing in pattern".  In some cases, Swift can figure out what type our variable should be.  For example, with `var x = 10`, Swift can figure out that `x`'s type should be `Int`.  If we want something else, we must specify.  But if we aren't assigning a value in the declaration, Swift has no idea and must be told: `var x: Int?`

---

What about the case where `x` exists at a different scope?

Well, Swift allows variable shadowing.  That is to say, a variable declared at one scope hides a variable declared at another scope.

So, for example:

```
class Foo {
    let x = 10

    func foo(value: Int) -> Int {
        let a = value * self.x
        let x = 10
        return a * x
    }
}
```

Now we can use *some* `x` before we've declared a locally scoped `x`, but these are different variables.  Also, perhaps most importantly, notice the `self.` prepended to `x` here.  It's required.  Without it, Swift will refuse to compile this code and will complain: "Use of local variable 'x' before its declaration."

---

However, within functions of classes is not the only place we can shadow variables.  We can also do it within `if` blocks (among other places) which is where things can get a little more confusing.  Consider this:

```
class Foo {
    let x = 10

    func foo(value: Int) -> Int {
        print(x)
        if x > 3 {
            let x = 2
            print(x)
        }
        return x
    }
}
```

Here, we've used `x` twice before declaring it.  And we didn't have to make use of the `self.` and it doesn't complain and compiles perfectly fine.  But it's important to note that *outside* the `if` block (including the `x > 3` conditional) the `x` we're referencing is the instance variable, but inside the `if` block, we've created a new variable called `x` which shadows the instance variable.  We can also create the same sort of shadowing by using `if let` and `if var` constructs (but not `guard let`).

The result of calling this function will be that the value `10` is printed, we enter the `if` block, the value of `2` is printed, then we exit the `if` block and the value of `10` is returned.

---

Now let's through `var` into the mix here.  First, if you aren't already aware, you should start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002209/2792531) which explains the difference between `let` and `var` (one is a constant, the other is not).

Let's combine `let` vs `var` with scoping and variable shadowing to see how it effects things.

```
class Foo {
    let x = 10

    func foo(value: Int) -> Int {
        print(x)
        if x > 3 {
            var x = 2
            while x < 10 {
                print(x)
                x += 3
            }
            return x
        }
        return x
    }
}
```

Okay, so this is the same as before but with a slightly more complicated bit within the `if` block.

Here, our locally-scoped variable is declared as a `var` while our instance variable remains a constant `let`.  We cannot modify the instance variable, but we can modify the local variable.  And we do so, on each iteration of the `while` loop.

But importantly, this variable is an entirely different variable from the instance variable.  It might as well have a completely different name (and in practice, it basically always *should* have a different name).  So modifying our local variable `x` doesn't change anything about our more broadly scoped instance variable `x`.  They're different variables that reside in different memory locations.  And once a variable is declared as a `let` or a `var`, that variable cannot be changed to the other.

Answer (score 2):

'let' and 'var' do not have a difference in scope.

> Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any
>   function, method, closure, or type context. Local variables are
>   variables that are defined within a function, method, or closure
>   context.