# Optional let and optional var inside a class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new to Swift and stuck in a problem.

When I use `optional let` inside a class it is giving the error "`Class className has no initializers`".

But when I write the same code using `optional var`, it shows no error.

For example:

The following code give me error:`Class className has no initializers`

```
class className: UIViewController
{
    let nearbyPlaceRadius : Int?    

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

The following code gives me no error.

```
class className: UIViewController
{
    var nearbyPlaceRadius : Int?    

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `let` is immutable. Once you have defined a variable or object using `let` keyword you can't change it, while using `var` you can mutate it any time.

That's the reason, it say `class has no initializers`

```
let someThing: Int? //Wrong
let someThing: Int = 100 //Correct
```

For reference: [What is the difference between `let` and `var` in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

> Update:

You can use let keyword with initializer.

```
let name: String?

init (name: String) {
    println("Initializing: \(name)")
    self.name = name
}
```

Comment: But even if I don't initialize a value to it, it must take it as nil since it is an optional constant.

Comment: Nope, for `let` keyword it will not work! But if you will declare `let` with `nil` what will be the purpose of it ? Bcaz you can assign any value to it later? @PGDev

Comment: @SohilR.Memon the question was about optional let.

Answer (score 5):

```
    let nearbyPlaceRadius : Int?
```

Actually you can have above line in your code and its not wrong. But if you do so, you have to write an `init` method and set it's value inside that method.