# What's the point of READ-only variables when you have LET?

Tags: swift

For example:

```
var dogName : String {
 return "Buster"
}
```

VS..

```
let dogName = "Buster"
```

Let's say we're declaring each of these at the top level of a class as instance properties. Are these just two ways of doing the same thing? If not, what's the point of having a read-only variable?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`let\` and \`var\` in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

Comment: I think you misunderstand that the first example is a computed property.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a read-only property doesn't exist in a vacuum. Normally such a property is found as part of a class or struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me try to sum up what the other answers are saying while also adding missing information that I think is critical in order to understand this.

### Properties

Properties are simply values that are associated with an object and may be queried in a trivial amount of time without the need (or ability) for parameters like methods have.

### Stored Properties

When you create a stored property, whether with `let` or `var`, the value assigned at any given point in time will be stored in memory, which is why it is called a stored property.

```
var name = "Matt"
```

For variables using `var`, the value is stored in memory in a way that makes it mutable (editable). You can reassign the value at will and it will replace the previous value **stored in memory**.

```
let name = "Matt"
```

For constants using `let`, the value is also stored in memory, but in such a way that it may not be changed **after the first time assigning to it**.

### Computed Properties

Computed properties are not stored in memory. As [ganzogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577432/ganzogo) says in the comments, computed properties act similarly to methods, but do not take parameters. When deciding when to use a computed property or a function with no parameters, the Swift API Design Guidelines recommend using a computed property when it will simply create or fetch, and then return the value, provided that this takes a trivial amount of time.

```
var fullName: String {
    return firstName + lastName
}
```

Here, we assume that `firstName` and `lastName` are already properties on the object. There is no sense of initialization with this property because it is not stored anywhere. It is fetched on demand **every time**. That is why there is no sense to doing anything like the following:

```
var dogName : String {
    return "Buster"
}
```

This has no benefit over a stored property except that no memory will be used in storing the `String` "Buster".

In fact, this is a simplified version of computed properties. You will notice that the Swift Language Guide describes the use of both `get` and `set` in a computed property. `set` allows you to update the state of other variables when one sets a computed variable. For example:

```
var stored: Int

var computed: Int {

    get {
        return stored + 5
    }

    set {
        stored = newValue - 5
    }

}
```

Some useful applications of this were pointed out by Rajan's answer, for example getting and setting volume from `width`, `height`, and `depth`.

A read-only computed var is just a computed var which specifies only a getter, in which case the `get` keyword and brackets are not required.

### Read-Only for Access Control

When developing modules such as frameworks, it is often useful to have a variable only be modifiable from within that object or framework and have it be read-only to the public.

```
private var modifiableItem: String

public var item: String {
    return modifiableItem
}
```

The idea here is that `modifiableItem` should only be mutable from within the object that defined it. The `private` keyword ensures that it is only accessible within the scope of the object that created it and making it a  `var` ensures that it may be modified. The `public var item`, then, is a computed variable that is exposed to the public that enables anyone to read, but not mutate the variable.

As Hamish notes in the comments, this is more concisely expressible by using `private(set)`:

```
public private(set) var item: String
```

This is probably the best way to go about it, but the previous code (using a private stored property and public computed one) demonstrates the effect.

Comment: Note that you can have private setters on public stored properties, e.g `public private(set) var item : String`, which is probably a better alternative to having a public computed property with a private backing variable.

Comment: Wow. Totally forgot about that. I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome explanation, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

```
let dogName = "Buster"
```

means that the `dogName` variable can't be changed later on once assigned  `"Buster"` and it becomes **constant**

```
var dogName : String {
 return "Buster"
}
```

It is a computed read only property where you can have some calculation which can be changed as it is a var but in a way defined below:

The computed property can be changed like

```
var dogName : String {
     return "Stress"+"Buster"
}
```

Consider this example from Apple Docs

```
struct Cuboid {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0, depth = 0.0
    var volume: Double {
        return width * height * depth
    }
}
let fourByFiveByTwo = Cuboid(width: 4.0, height: 5.0, depth: 2.0)
print("the volume of fourByFiveByTwo is \(fourByFiveByTwo.volume)")
```

It will print

```
// Prints "the volume of fourByFiveByTwo is 40.0"
```

Here the volume is calculated when you initialize the object of struct `Cuboid` and is computed at run time. If it was let, then you have to initialize it before using by some constant.

If you want to read more about it, read the **Computed Properties** section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Comment: I'm Sorry, I am using Swift playground and am still under the impression that a read-only variable cannot be written to and changed once it is declared, thus being functionally equivalent to 'let'.

Comment: I just posted an example for you of cuboid as a struct. to make you understand better

Comment: A little explanation also added. Focus of `volume` property

Answer (score 1):

A read-only property in a class/struct means that you can't change the value of the property for that instance of the class/struct. It prevents me from doing:

```
someObject.dogName = "Buddy" // This fails - read-only property
```

However, I can still do this:

```
var someVariable = someObject.dogName // someVariable now is "Buster"
someVariable = "Buddy" // This is OK, it's now "Buddy"
```

A `let` constant means you won't be changing the value of that specific constant in that block of code.

```
let someName = "Buster"
someName = "Buddy" // This fails - someName is a constant
```

Comment: True, but functionally equivalent yes? I mean, the end result is that you are receiving a value that cannot be changed once initialized.

Comment: @user7024499 Not at all. These two things have nothing to do with each other. See my update.

Comment: Maybe 'functionally equivalent' isn't the right term. I mean in the big scheme of things, one of the USAGES you gain with both of these is the ability to set a value and make it restricted from changing once it is set. So in an instance object, the value of the property is restricted from changing b/c it is read only, and with LET, you won't be able to change the value either way

Comment: But they prevent the changing of two completely different things. `let` only protects that specific local variable. The read-only property protects all instances of that property.

Comment: Got you. However, when you use 'let' as a member in a class, is it not also preventing you from changing that value for all child instances of that object type? I.E. class Dog {  let name = "buster" } ... for all instances, the name HAS to be buster.. it cannot be changed because let is a constant. In effect, doing the same thing as a read-only variable which cannot be changed.

Comment: True but typically your read-only property returns a dynamic value, not a hardcoded string.

Comment: Okay so safe to say a huge advantage of a read-only variable (or property in the case that it's a top level class member) is that you can write code that will compute a dynamic value based on other properties in the class before those values have been initialized. Reason being because a computed variable is actually just a shorthand for a function.  With LET, I'm assuming you're more compiler error prone if you do that type of thing inside a class before having initialized an instance.

Comment: Yes. And you would never use a read-only property other than as a top-level class member.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, they are 2 ways of doing the same thing. However, you can do a lot more with a computed property. For example:

```
var dogName: String {
  return firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

Here, `firstName` and `lastName` might not be known at initialization time. This is not possible to do with a simple `let` property.

It might help you to think of a computed property as a method with no parameters.

Comment: How about with a Computed Initializer? We can do the same thing with a computed initializer with no compile time error right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "computed initializer", but the point is that in my example, `dogName` is dynamic.

Comment: Cool thanks. Computed initializer is like var myNumber : Int = { if (3 ==3) { return 3} }() *must be invoked immediately

Comment: Ah I see. Yes - that is only called once, whereas the block for a computed property is called every time that property is accessed. It might help you to think of a computed property as a method with no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different cases:

1) **Value type:**

```
struct DogValueType {

    var name: String

}

let dog1 = DogValueType(name: "Buster")

var dog2: DogValueType {
    return DogValueType(name: "Buster")
}

let dog3: DogValueType = {
    return DogValueType(name: "Buster")
}()
```

- `dog1` - `dog3` can't be changed or mutated
- `dog1` & `dog3` stores value
- `dog3` computes value each time you accessing it

2) **Reference type:**

```
class DogReferenceType {

    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let dog4 = DogReferenceType(name: "Buster")

var dog5: DogReferenceType {
    return DogReferenceType(name: "Buster")
}

let dog6: DogReferenceType = {
    return DogReferenceType(name: "Buster")
}()
```

- `dog4` - `dog6` can't be changed, but can be mutated
- `dog4` & `dog6` stores reference to an object.
- `dog5` creates object each time you accessing it