# What's the difference between "var" and "let" in Swift?

Tags: swift

I get that `var` is for defining variables and `let` is for defining constants.

My issue is, I am "able" to change my `let` constants.  For example, my test code takes in two inputs from the user, their name and emails.  When a button is pressed, it will update two labels.

However, when I change the inputs, it will also change the labels.  So why doesn't it crash or anything?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let text = nameInput.text
        let email = emailInput.text

        label.text = text
        label2.text = email
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`let\` and \`var\` in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

Comment: `var` lets you change the value that it points to `let` does not.  `IBOutlet` needs to be `var` because the values are assigned AFTER the object is constructed

Comment: Where do you think you are attempting to change a `let` constant? None of your code makes any such attempt.

Comment: A thing may be a constant yet mutable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/27366050#27366050

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a **variable**, it **can** be changed once defined

`let` is a **constant**, it **can't** be changed once defined.

`IBOutlet` needs to be a variable (`var`) because the values are defined **after** the object is made.

Here you are not changing you variables:

```
let text = nameInput.text
let email = emailInput.text

label.text = text
label2.text = email
```

Because the labels are variables (`var`), they can be changed. Every time you click your button, the constants (`let`) is being re-made and for this reason they are not being **changed** but redefined as a **new** constant.

Comment: Correction: they are not really being redefined. Once the scope of the action is done the constants are de-allocated, so next time the button gets tapped they are created afresh.