# Global 'let' declaration requires an initializer expression

Tags: swift

I am working on iOS code with Xcode 10.2.1.

I have an issue when declaring a let global variable:

```
import UIKit

import CouchbaseLiteSwift

private let database: Database
```

This gives the compiler error below:

```
Global 'let' declaration requires an initializer expression
```

I don't know how to make `database` a global variable in this case. I searched about it, but all says about some int or string initialization but not when initializing classes like `Database`. Because, Couchbase's `Database` class is a big class. I can't do it with `"= null"`

Any help please?

Comment: You need an `=` followed by some appropriate initialization.

Comment: Do you want a global variable (as you state) or a global constant? A let is a constant, so you have to give it an initial value at declaration (e.g. `private let database: Database = Database()`, or just `private let database = Database()`. If you want a variable then make it `var`. Everything you found whilst searching is correct, even if talking about an int or string.

Comment: I tried both, but it says "Missing argument for parameter 'name' in call"

Comment: Basically, just change it to be `private let database: Database?`

Comment: private let database: Database? didn't work either. Same error Global 'let' declaration requires an initializer expression

Comment: @Stella Given the error, clearly you need something like `= Database(name: someNameHere)`. Look at the documentation for this `Database` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a variable if you're not sure what it is so that later you can change it:

```
private var database: Database?
```

There's no point in [defining a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift) if you're not going to actually define it as *something*.

Answer (score 1):

The distinguishing feature of a `let` variable is that it is assigned to *exactly once* before being read.

When a `let` declaration is a **local variable**, Swift can analyze the code to make sure that the variable will be initialized exactly once before it is used. This is why you can declare a local `let` variable with no initial value. For example:

```swift
let greeting: String

if(light.isOn()) {
  greeting = "Hello!"
} else {
  greeting = "Who’s there?!"
}

// Now it is OK to use greeting, because we _know_ the code took
// exactly one branch of the if, and each branch initializes greeting

print(greeting)  // OK
```

With an **instance variable**, you don't need to specify an initial value as long as every initializer sets it exactly once.

However, with a **global variable**, the compiler can't really make any guarantees about who will assign to it when. You therefore have to give it an initial value right on the spot.

As @rmaddy points out in the comments, it might look like this:

```swift
private let database = Database(name: "foo")
```

If initialization takes multiple statements, you can batch them up in a closure like this:

```swift
private let database = {
  let config = readConfigFile()
  guard let dbName = config["database"] else {
    fatalError("Missing config for 'database'")
  }
  return Database(name: dbName)
}()
```

If you must make it a global, but it just isn't possible to initialize it until later, you must make it a `var`:

```swift
private var database: Database?
```

…or if you want any attempt to use it before it’s initialized to be a crasher:

```swift
private var database: Database!
```