# var to let type conversion or vice versa in swift:

Tags: swift, immutability

Can a **var** type be changed into **let** type or vice versa in swift. I try to search it online but there is no such content available online.

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002092/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var-in-swift)

Comment: The question does not make any sense, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the mutability of a variable once it has been declared. However, you can create a mutable/immutable copy of any variable.

```
let immutable = 21
var mutableCopy = immutable
mutableCopy = 2

var mutable = 3
let immutableCopy = 4
```

You also have to be aware though that mutability and copying means different things for reference and value types.

Answer (score 0):

conversion from `let` to `var`

```
let a = "" /* Constant */
var b = a /* Variable */
b = "b"
```

conversion from `var` to `let`

```
var c = "" /* Variable */
let d = c /* Constant */
```

> **Declaring Constants and Variables** Constants and variables must be declared before they’re used. You declare constants with the let
>   keyword and variables with the var keyword. [source](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)

**Struct (Value Type) vs Class (Reference Type)**

```
class TotoClass {
    var str = "str"
}

struct TotoStruct {
    var str = "str"
}

let classToto = TotoClass()
let structToto = TotoStruct()

classToto.str = "new Str"
structToto.str = "new Str"
```

last line doesn't compile and there will be an error

> Cannot assign to property: 'structToto' is a 'let' constant