# Python: weird behavior of list append function

Tags: python, list

I'm a newbie in Python.

I try to make a Kruskal algo. Here is my code:

```
#c={('v','a'):5,('v','g'):5,('g','a'):5,('v','b'):7,('v','e'):4,('f','e'):8,('f','b'):8,('f','c'):11,('c','e'):9,('c','d'):7,('c','b'):9,('e','d'):8}
#n=8

def argmin(c):
    m=1e100
    r=()
    for i in c:
       if c[i]<m:
           m=c[i]
           r=i
    return r

def kruskal (n, c):
    T=[]
    B=[]
    while len(T)<n-1:
        E=argmin(c)
        c.pop(E)
        e=[]
        e+=E
        a0=0
        a1=0
        f0=-1
        f1=-1
        cross=0
#        print('e avant',e)
        for i in range(len(B)):
            for j in range(len(B[i])):
                if e[0]==B[i][j]:
                    cross+=1
                    f0=i   
                if e[1]==B[i][j]:
                    cross+=1
                    f1=i                        
            if cross==2: break
            else: cross=0
        if cross==2: continue
#        print('e apres',e)
        T.append(e)
#        print('T',T)
        if f0!=-1 and f1!=-1:
            B[f0].extend(B[f1])
            B.pop(f1)
        elif f0!=-1:
            B[f0].extend(e[1])
        elif f1!=-1:
            B[f1].extend(e[0])
        else :
            B.append(e)        
#        print('B', B)                
    return T
```

The problem I have is in the line where is: "T.append(e)"
In the result T[0] is not what I expect.
if I input the following:

```
c={('v','a'):5,('v','g'):5,('g','a'):5,('v','b'):7,('v','e'):4,('f','e'):8,('f','b'):8,('f','c'):11,('c','e'):9,('c','d'):7,('c','b'):9,('e','d'):8}

n=8
```

Then I call my function:
kruskal(8, c)
I get:

`[['v', 'e', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'd'], ['v', 'g'], ['v', 'a'], ['v', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'b'], ['e', 'd']]`

Where as I expect the following:

```
[['v', 'e'], ['v', 'g'], ['v', 'a'], ['v', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'b'], ['e', 'd']]
```

Comment: in an iteration I have this:
T= [['v', 'e'], ['g', 'a'], ['v', 'a']]
e= ['v', 'b']
Then after a "T.append(e)", I get:
T= [['v', 'e', 'g', 'a'], ['g', 'a'], ['v', 'a'], ['v', 'b']]

So what's wrong here sirs.

Comment: Check the part where you do `e += E`, in this chunk, you have `e` which is a list and `E` which is a tuple, so it extends `e` with the elements of `E`. You may want to use `append` if `e` is supposed to be growing over iteration, or empty `e` at the beginning of the iteration.

Comment: Try it with a small amount of data, one value for example, or even none. See what happens.

Comment: I still don't get it!
yes I'm converting E the tuple into e the list. e is emptied when I had e=[].
Why in an iteration T.append(e) e get appended both to the end of T and to T[0] too???!!

Comment: Please uncomment the "print" and try the code with inputs provided.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking for all your code.But something is found that, You are appending `references` of `list` sometime.So to simply fix:

```
from copy import deepcopy

T.append(deepcopy(e)) #in place of T.append(e)
```

Will give output as

```
[['v', 'e'], ['g', 'a'], ['v', 'a'], ['v', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'b'], ['e', 'd']]
```

**Example**

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
b.append(3)

>>>a
[1,2,3]

>>>b
[1,2,3]
```

**What is happening here**

```
a = [1,2]
b = a

>>>id(a), id(b)
(140526873334272, 140526873334272)
```

That is list `[1,2]` is `tagged` by two variables `a` and `b`. So any changes to list will affect every `varables` tagged to it.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer by itzmeontv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29251005/838992) is correct regarding the underlying reason for your problem the first member of `T` is a mutable list, which you then modify further on in your code.  The code path why this happens in your case is a little complicated:

1. On the first iteration through your algorithm, you append `e` to `T` - so `T[0]` refers to the list name `e` at that point (contents `['v','e']`)
2. On that same iteration, you always hit this block:

   ```
    else :
        B.append(e)
   ```
3. This means that `B[0]` now refers to the list named `e` as well - i.e. `T[0]` refers to **the same list** as that in `B[0]` and any changes to `B[0]` will be reflected in `T[0]` as lists are mutable.
4. The next iteration then creates a new `e` - **but** the list referred to in `B[0]` and `T[0]` is still that same list i.e. `['v','e']`
5. You then continue to extend this list when you do `B[f0].extend(B[f1])` in the cases where `f0` is zero

This is a symptom of assigning a list not making a copy in Python, a detailed treatment of which is given [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) if you want to deepen your understanding.  A range of options of how to append your list to `T` [is given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/838992) along with [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612990/838992) - you might, for instance, like to write `T.append(e[:])`, with the slice notation implicitly making a copy of `e` at the point you append it.

One thing you might want to consider is whether you need the members of `T` to be [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects) once they are added to `T`.  If you do not - an option may be to append `tuples` rather than `lists` - i.e.

```
T.append(tuple(e))
```