# Mutable and immutable objects in java

Tags: java, oop

Can  anyone  explain  me  on  a  simple  example  the  difference  between  mutable  and  immutable  objects  in  java?

Comment: I'm sure there're are many resources available. This [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable) could be helpful.

Comment: Here's a good link about the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects

Answer (score 2):

**Mutable** objects are objects whose state can be changed.

A state in Java is implemented with data fields.

An example of mutable object:

```
class Counter {
    private int i = 0;

    public void increase() {
         i++;
    }
}
```

So `i` represents an internal state of the class `Counter` here. And it can be changed as time goes by:

```
 Counter counter = new Counter();
 counter.increase(); // somewhere in the code
```

On the other hand, **Immutable** objects are objects whose state can't be changed once the object is created/initialized.

These objects should not have 'mutators' - setters, or in general methods that change an internal state.

Here is an example of an immutable object:

```
public final class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age  = age;
    } 

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

As you see - although this class maintains the state (in fields `name` and `age`), it's impossible to change this state after the object is created (the constructor is called).

Comment: To make Person really immutable you should also make the class `final`, to prevent malicious/stupid users from extending it and adding mutable data/behaviour or overriding one of the existing methods to make them mutate the underlying object.

Comment: yep, you're right. I'm changing the code